# What's the difference between Invoke() and BeginInvoke()

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, invoke, begininvoke

Just wondering what the difference between `BeginInvoke()` and `Invoke()` are?

Mainly what each one would be used for.

EDIT: What is the difference between creating a threading object and calling invoke on that and just calling `BeginInvoke()` on a delegate? or are they the same thing?

Comment: Statement should be:-
**Note**: Both `ref` and `out` parameter treated same at compile-time but different at run-time.

Answer (score 632, accepted):

Do you mean `Delegate.Invoke`/`BeginInvoke` or `Control.Invoke`/`BeginInvoke`?

- `Delegate.Invoke`: Executes synchronously, on the same thread.
- `Delegate.BeginInvoke`: Executes asynchronously, on a `threadpool` thread.
- `Control.Invoke`: Executes on the UI thread, but calling thread waits for completion before continuing.
- `Control.BeginInvoke`: Executes on the UI thread, and calling thread doesn't wait for completion.

Tim's answer mentions when you might want to use `BeginInvoke` - although it was mostly geared towards `Delegate.BeginInvoke`, I suspect.

For Windows Forms apps, I would suggest that you should *usually* use `BeginInvoke`. That way you don't need to worry about deadlock, for example - but you need to understand that the UI may not have been updated by the time you next look at it! In particular, you shouldn't modify data which the UI thread might be about to use for display purposes. For example, if you have a `Person` with `FirstName` and `LastName` properties, and you did:

```
person.FirstName = "Kevin"; // person is a shared reference
person.LastName = "Spacey";
control.BeginInvoke(UpdateName);
person.FirstName = "Keyser";
person.LastName = "Soze";
```

Then the UI may well end up displaying "Keyser Spacey". (There's an outside chance it could display "Kevin Soze" but only through the weirdness of the memory model.)

Unless you have this sort of issue, however, `Control.BeginInvoke` is easier to get right, and will avoid your background thread from having to wait for no good reason. Note that the Windows Forms team has guaranteed that you can use `Control.BeginInvoke` in a "fire and forget" manner - i.e. without ever calling `EndInvoke`. This is not true of async calls in general: normally every BeginXXX should have a corresponding EndXXX call, usually in the callback.

Comment: I'm confused by "Control.Invoke: Executes on the UI thread, but calling thread waits for completion before continuing. Control.BeginInvoke: Executes on the UI thread, and calling thread doesn't wait for completion" I don't think Control.Invoke/BeginInvoke executes on the UI thread, they should execute on the thread that owns the Control's handle.( which is not always the UI thread ). See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Then why would ppl use Invoke over BeingInvoke? Shouldn't there be some advantages over using Invoke. Both executes processes in the background, just that one is on the same thread, the other on different thread?

Comment: @Jon: While I am using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke my code is working fine and in Dispatcher.Invoke my application making me wait for few seconds then it initializes all controls then launching, Can you please help me to find out exactly in which place I stuck ?

Comment: @All: Can anybody give a brief idea on Dispatcher.BeginInvoke and Dispatcher.Invoke ? How they works and what they doing, everything.

Comment: @SharpUrBrain: Well, what have you read, and which bits didn't you understand?

Comment: @Jon I am very new to .net Framework and I never used this Dispatcher class, Here you told something about Control.BeginInvoke. Is that same as Dispatcher.BeginInvoke?

Comment: @SharpUrBrain: Control.BeginInvoke is sort of the equivalent of Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, but for WinForms (whereas Dispatcher is for WPF and Silverlight).

Comment: @Jon: Can you please share me any article or sample through which I'll get brief idea on Dispatcher(How it works and about its implementation) ?

Comment: @SharpUrBrain: I don't have any particular articles to hand - I'd just be doing a web search for "Dispatcher threading WPF BeginInvoke".

Comment: @Jon: So as you suggested in the above answer to use BiginInvoke for Windows Forms apps then is it also same in case of Dispatcher ?

Comment: @SharpUrBrain: Yes, except you need to get hold of the appropriate dispatcher instead of calling BeginInvoke directly on the control.

Comment: @Jon: oh OK Many many Thanks Jon, I am still having less knowledge on Dispatcher so let me come up with some basic idea and again if I'll face any Problem then is it OK to disturb you ? :)

Comment: @SharpUrBrain: I would suggest you ask a specific question rather than continuing in comments - and of course check whether the same question has already been asked by someone else first.

Comment: @AZ: Yes, by "on the UI thread" he means on the particular "UI thread" which owns that particular Control's handle.  Typically, there is only one UI thread, but it is possible to have multiple UI threads, and in advanced applications there are reasons why you would want them.  Technically, any (normal?) thread could start a UI message pump and become a UI thread--and could later shut down the message pump and no longer be a UI thread.  (I assume that's not something to try on a threadpool thread, though.)

Comment: Here is, in addition to the answer, about UI Threading Model (including Control.Invoke and Control.BeginInvoke) with some visualization: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19023209/2042090

Comment: A very clear and straight forward answer, i always forget the meaning between them, everytimes i return to this post.

Comment: Dispatcher invoke and begininvoke will also behave in a manner as control described above.

Answer (score 56):

Building on Jon Skeet's reply, there are times when you want to invoke a delegate and wait for its execution to complete before the current thread continues.  In those cases the Invoke call is what you want.

In multi-threading applications, you may not want a thread to wait on a delegate to finish execution, especially if that delegate performs I/O (which could make the delegate and your thread block).

In those cases the BeginInvoke would be useful.  By calling it, you're telling the delegate to start but then your thread is free to do other things in parallel with the delegate.

Using BeginInvoke increases the complexity of your code but there are times when the improved performance is worth the complexity.

Answer (score 32):

The difference between `Control.Invoke()` and `Control.BeginInvoke()` is,

- `BeginInvoke()` will schedule the asynchronous action on the GUI thread. When the asynchronous action is scheduled, your code continues. Some time later (you don't know exactly when) your asynchronous action will be executed
- `Invoke()` will execute your asynchronous action (on the GUI thread) and wait until your action has completed.

A logical conclusion is that a delegate you pass to `Invoke()` can have out-parameters or a return-value, while a delegate you pass to `BeginInvoke()` cannot (you have to use EndInvoke to retrieve the results).

Answer (score 27):

Just to give a short, working example to see an effect of their difference

```
new Thread(foo).Start();

private void foo()
{
  this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    (ThreadStart)delegate()
    {
        myTextBox.Text = "bing";
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
    });
  MessageBox.Show("done");
}
```

If use **BeginInvoke**, MessageBox pops simultaneous to the text update. If use **Invoke**, MessageBox pops after the 3 second sleep. Hence, showing the effect of an asynchronous (**BeginInvoke**) and a synchronous (**Invoke**) call.

Answer (score 10):

Delegate.BeginInvoke() asynchronously queues the call of a delegate and returns control immediately.  When using Delegate.BeginInvoke(), you should call Delegate.EndInvoke() in the callback method to get the results.

Delegate.Invoke() synchronously calls the delegate in the same thread.

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb(VS.71).aspx)

Answer (score 10):

Just adding why and when to use Invoke().

Both Invoke() and BeginInvoke() marshal the code you specify to the dispatcher thread.

But unlike BeginInvoke(), Invoke() stalls your thread until the dispatcher executes your code. **You might want to use Invoke() if you need to pause an asynchronous operation until the user has supplied some sort of feedback.**

For example, you could call Invoke() to run a snippet of code that shows an OK/Cancel dialog box. After the user clicks a button and your marshaled code completes, the invoke() method will return, and you can act upon the user's response.

See Pro WPF in C# chapter 31