# need help to search MS Access Database C#

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

i have created MS Access Database and it is working fine (ADD, DELETE, Update) now i need to use search function. i need to search using text box and a button.
i need to know how to search database using primary key and get those row values in to a text box or list box

I did it like this,

```
        con.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd_ni = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd_ni.Connection = con;
        cmd_ni.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE vehicle_num = @vehicle_num";
        cmd_ni.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd_ni.Parameters.Add("id", OleDbType.VarChar);
        cmd_ni.Parameters["id"].Value = nu_m;

        OleDbDataReader dr1 = cmd_ni.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr1.Read())
        {
            string ni;

            ni = dr1["vehicle_num"].ToString();

            if (nu_m == ni)
            {
                Class1.nn = ni;

                DialogResult r = MessageBox.Show("the details");

                if (r == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    //here i need the code to select the data row & show it in textbox.
                }

            }
        }
        dr1.Close();
        con.Close();
```

after this point i cannot understand what to do. please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, You should try to google the answer first. But here are some resources that will help you on your way.

You should just add a textbox to your winform, and a button and on button click execute the code you show above. The only thing you need to add is a new parameter to your where statement.

This looks like a good walkthrough for you [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mrXJDKbfg4g)
and this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824905/suggestions-for-implementing-a-simple-search-for-business-objects-in-a-net-wi) looks at how to best structure it.

And after reading the answers look at **related** on the right hand side of the questions, There are many questions there that are looking in depth at this.