# InvokeRequired and ToolStripStatusLabel

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, invokerequired

In my application I have class that is responsible for all database actions. It is called from main class and uses delegates to call methods after action is complete.
Because it is asynchronous I must use invoke on my GUI, so I've created a simple extensions method:

```
 public static void InvokeIfRequired<T>(this T c, Action<T> action)
            where T: Control
        {
            if (c.InvokeRequired)
            {
                c.Invoke(new Action(() => action(c)));
            }
            else
            {
                action(c);
            }
        }
```

This works fine when I try to call it on textBox:

```
textBox1.InvokeIfRequired(c => { c.Text = "it works!"; });
```

but when I try to call it on ToolStripStatusLabel or ToolStripProgressBar I get an error:

> The type 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel' cannot be used as
>   type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method
>   'SimpleApp.Helpers.InvokeIfRequired(T, System.Action)'. There is
>   no implicit reference conversion from
>   'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control'.

I know that this is probably a simple fix, but I just can handle it :/

Comment: Maybe this similar question will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1127973/how-do-i-make-cross-threaded-calls-to-a-toolstripstatuslabel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is because ToolStripItem (base for those two causing an error) is a Component and not a Control.
Try calling your extension method on the tool strip that owns them and adjust your delegate
methods.

Comment: I fount just a second ago the same info on Google :) But how I should access ToolStripStatusLable from statusStrip? So I can pass statusStrip to my method?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip.items.aspx

MSDN is your friend :)

Comment: You're fast :) but how to access Items? only by index or can I do it by name? For example if I name ToolStripStatusLabel 'status' how can I access it in my delegate? only like `statusStrip1.Items[0]`? I'm asking because I will be adding controls to statusStrip dynamically and I can mess up index of my control.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25b5ws77.aspx

It was just 2 click away... please read documentation

Comment: Don't ya love this place? :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add up to the accepted solution. You can get the control from the component by using the GetCurrentParent method of the ToolStripStatusLabel.

Instead of doing `toolStripStatusLabel1.InvokeIfRequired`, do `toolStripStatusLabel1.GetCurrentParent().InvokeIfRequired`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been working with Control, but after getting your answer, I just finished my work.

Answer (score 2):

**Extension method using** `GetCurrentParent().InvokeRequired`

```
public static void ToolStripStatusInvokeAction<TControlType>(this TControlType control, Action<TControlType> del)
    where TControlType : ToolStripStatusLabel
    {
        if (control.GetCurrentParent().InvokeRequired)
            control.GetCurrentParent().Invoke(new Action(() => del(control)));
        else
            del(control);
    }
```

**Calling the ToolStripStatusInvokeAction Extension:**

```
toolStripAppStatus.ToolStripStatusInvokeAction(t =>
{ 
    t.Text= "it works!";
    t.ForeColor = Color.Red;
});
```