# Extension method or Inheritance?

Tags: .net, wpf, observablecollection

I have used `ObservableCollection` for **DataBinding** in my `WPF` application where I am binding the collection to `DataGrids` and `ComboBoxes`. And due to a requirement, where I needed to remove objects from the collection based on a condition, I implemented the `RemoveAll` functionality, like `List`, using `Extension method`.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132262/extension-methods-versus-inheritance) posts specifies a few merits of `Inheritance` over `Extension methods` but is not very specific for my case as this was the only method I needed to add and I don't intend to add another `Extension method` for the Collection.

I would like to know if it would be better for me to have this implemented as `Extension method` as is or should I think about inheriting the class and add it as a `Instance method`?

Also, I would like to know if there is any performance difference between the two as it has not been discussed in the mentioned post.

Comment: considering to use `Clear` as name, as this is well known for removing everything in a list.another point is that the compiler will use the objects-implementation of `Clear` if available (is often better in performance).

Comment: Well, Clear() removes everything and that's not my point.

Comment: ahh, i forgot that RemoveAll uses a predicat-Delegate......sorry!you're absolutely right

Comment: Yes, it does and that's why I had to resort to the Extension method for the same as this is not available with the ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of one method I would use an Extension Method. In this instance it would mean your code can continue to use `ObservableCollection<T>` without needing to maintain a custom type.

Extension methods simply boil down to static method calls when compiled, so I can't imagine performance is any worse than with inheritance. If anything it should be the same or better.

Personal preference is usually what drives the choice of extension methods.

Answer (score 4):

If you plan on enhancing just the ObservableCollection more than just RemoveAll(), then subclass it and add your functionality. If you want to add RemoveAll() to more than just an ObservableCollection, then you could create an extension method that handles more than just ObservableCollections, by targeting IEnumerable or another generic parent in the heirarchy instead. In that method, you could test if the collection supports CollectionChanged, and handle it appropriately.

There's no right or wrong answer here, it's whatever suits your needs.

Comment: Well, as I have specified, I don't intend to add any other functionality and I do use IList often when I don't have to do any binding and that already has the method, I don't think I need to extend this to any other type. But good point (+1) and I might use this advice in future.

Answer (score 1):

With an Extensionmethod you can extend an Interface which results in extending every implementor of that interface.

I would do it with an extension method of `System.Collections.IList`.
`System.Collections.IList` is used everywhere...

```
public class static Extension
{
   public static void RemoveAll(this System.Collections.IList list)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

this will extend nearly every collection implementation.

Comment: Well, this looks good but I guess I do not need to extend this functionality to other types right now. But a good suggestion. +1.