# Using a Task Continuation to Stack Jobs

Tags: c#, winforms, queue, task-parallel-library

All, I have a mathod called `TaskSpin` that runs the passed method on a background thread using TPL.

```
public TaskSpin(Func asyncMethod, object[] methodParameters)
{
    ...
    asyncTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(() => 
        asyncMethod(uiScheduler, methodParameters));

    asyncTask.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        ...
        // Finish the processing update UI etc.
        ...
        if (isStacked && task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
            ProcessNextTask(dataGridViewSite);
    }
    ...
}
```

This routine is well established to fire off one method at-a-time, but I have recently been required to queue multiple methods and run them sequentially. To do this (aided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11758271/626442)) I have written the following button click event handler

```
private void buttonProcAllUrg_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Build the stacker.
    Dictionary<Func<TaskScheduler, object[], bool>, object[]> taskPair = 
        new Dictionary<Func<TaskScheduler, object[], bool>, object[]>();
    this.taskQueue = 
        new Queue<KeyValuePair<Func<TaskScheduler, object[], bool>, object[]>>();

    // Populate the stacker.
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.DataGridViewDrg.Rows) 
    {
        KeyValuePair<Func<TaskScheduler, object[], bool>, object[]> task =
            new KeyValuePair<Func<TaskScheduler, object[], bool>, object[]>
            (BuildDrgDataForSite, DrgDataRowInfo(row.Index));     
        this.taskQueue.Enqueue(task); 
    }

    // Launch the queue.
    ProcessNextTask(this.DataGridViewDrg);
}
```

and the method ProcessNextTask is defined as

```
private void ProcessNextTask(DataGridView dataGridView) 
{     
    try     
    {
        // Queue empty.
        bIsStacked = true;
        if (this.taskQueue.Count <= 0)
        {
            bIsStacked = false;
            return;
        }

        // Launch new task.
        KeyValuePair<Func<TaskScheduler, object[], bool>, object[]> item = this.taskQueue.Dequeue();
        Task<bool> asyncBuildDataTask = null;
        TaskSpin(asyncBuildDataTask, uiScheduler, mainForm,
                    item.Key, item.Value, dataGridView,
                    "Process stack successfully executed", true, bIsStacked);
    }     
    catch(InvalidOperationException)    
    {
        // Nothing left in stack.
        bIsStacked = false;    
    }   
}
```

This works fine, but after the first task has run and the `ProcessNextTask` is called for the second (or more times) from the continuation, the GUI becomes unresponsive. What can I do to ensure the UI thread is not blocked upon the second call?

*Note. I have tried to launch the `ProcessNextTask` method on another thread using the UI thread synchronisation context*

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    ProcessNextTask(dataGridView);
}, CancellationToken.None, 
   TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, 
   uiScheduler);
```

*where `TaskScheduler uiSchduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchonisationContex();`.*

***Edit: I have attampted to create a `BlockingCollection` to facilitate what I want to do based on @Reed Copsey's answer below, but I have never done this and would welcome any advice here***

```
BlockingCollection<Action<object[]>> taskQueue = 
    new BlockingCollection<Action<object[]>>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.DataGridViewDrg.Rows) 
{
    Action<object[]> tmpAction = del => 
        {AsyncBuildDrgDataForSite(DrgDataRowInfo(row.Index)); };
    taskQueue.Add(tmpAction);
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why would I want to sack Steve Jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend thinking about this differently.

If you're trying to "stack jobs", it's typically better to rework the routine into a producer/consumer scenario.  `BlockingCollection<T>` provides the proper framework for this, as it provides a thread safe queue which you can just use to add in your work items, and then create a task to process them (via `GetConsumingEnumerable()`).  Once the items are done, you can update your UI, then restart the "producer" task as you add a new item, etc.

Comment: I have edited with a new attempt at what you have suggested. Could you have a look at it? It would be most appreciated. Thanks for your time...

Comment: @Killercam You're likely getting closure issues - you have to make a temporary in your foreach.  See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx