# Previous text still showing after update label text

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to update a labels text. When the original text contains multiple lines and I update the text to something with a single line the old multiple lines are still visible even when the text updates on the top line. Here is an example. How can I fix this?

```
PhotoText.Text = "Testing Some\nCode Out\nRight Now!"; //This shows 3 lines
PhotoText.Refresh();    
Thread.Sleep(1000);
PhotoText.Text = "New Text!"; //This shows 1 lines
PhotoText.Refresh();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: WHat platform are you working on? WinForms, WPF, UWP?

Comment: I'm working with WinForms

Comment: Where is this code called? It works when I call it from a Button click.

Comment: You have the label's AutoSize property set to True.  The shorter text makes the label smaller, the old pixels can only be overpainted when the label's Parent repaints itself.  So you also need PhotoText.Parent.Update().  Just don't hang the UI thread and you won't have problems like this.

Comment: Your code is perfectly find in my `WinForm` using default `Label` settings. Perhaps you may also want to post your `Label`'s property settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not block UI thread. Run long running tasks separately:

```
private void button46_Click(object sender, EventArgs ee)
{            
    new Task(() =>
    {
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler((o, e) => PhotoText.Text = "Testing Some\nCode Out\nRight Now!"));           
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        this.Invoke(new EventHandler((o, e) => PhotoText.Text = "New Text!"));
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Start();
}
```

`this` is a form, the `Invoke` runs `PhotoText.Text =...` on UI thread. You can also use `this.BeginInvoke` even without `EndInvoke` [(see more)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532722/is-endinvoke-optional-sort-of-optional-or-definitely-not-optional).

Answer (score -2):

Try to call

```
this.Refresh();
Application.DoEvents();
```

between each update.

Answer (score -3):

Try doing it with string

```
PhotoText.Text = "Testing Some\nCode Out\nRight Now!"; //This shows 3 lines
PhotoText.Refresh();    
Thread.Sleep(1000);
string phototext="New Text!";
PhotoText.Text = phototext; //This shows 1 lines
PhotoText.Refresh();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```