# Can I use BeginInvoke with a MulticastDelegate?

Tags: .net, multithreading, events, delegates, begininvoke

I want to raise a series of events from my library class, but I'm worried that some event subscribers will be rude and take a long time to process some events, thus blocking the thread that is raising the events. I thought I could protect the raising thread by using a thread pool thread to raise each event:

```
if (packet != null && DataPacketReceived != null)
{
    var args = new DataPacketEventArgs(packet);
    DataPacketReceived.BeginInvoke(this, args, null, null);
}
```

That works fine when there's only one subscriber to the event, but as soon as a second subscriber arrives, `DataPacketReceived` becomes a multicast delegate, and I get an argument exception with the error message, "The delegate must have only one target." Is there an easy way to raise the event on a separate thread, or do I have to start a thread and then raise the event from there?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found a similar question on [another site](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/273437-delegate-must-have-only-one-target), and of course Jon Skeet had answered it. For my scenario, I chose to raise the event for each subscriber on a separate thread:

```
if (packet != null && DataPacketReceived != null)
{
    var args = new DataPacketEventArgs(packet);
    var receivers = DataPacketReceived.GetInvocationList();
    foreach (EventHandler<DataPacketEventArgs> receiver in receivers)
    {
        receiver.BeginInvoke(this, args, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, but note that calling `BeginInvoke` on each individual subscriber does not necessarily mean that each will run on a separate thread. It's the thread-pool's business.

Comment: I've been looking at this issue a few times over the last few days, It's important to note that the objects in `receivers` aren't actually of type `EventHandler<DataPacketEventArgs>`, that's an explicit cast.