# Why does my eventhandler halt execution of the event raiser?

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, .net-4.0, task

Having searched extensively, I am still confused about some basic programming concepts regarding events, tasks and threads. Note that this is for .Net 4.0, no await/async.

This may well be a duplicate but if it is I haven't found it. I've embedded my questions in the Program part of the code, so as to not disrupt flow of reading.

event publisher:

```
public class Publisher  
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> ProgressChanged;

    public void Run(int iterations)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Will fire event in iteration {0} in a second", i);
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            OnProgressChanged();
        }
    }

    private void OnProgressChanged()
    {
        EventHandler<EventArgs> handler = ProgressChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty); // raise event
        }
    }
}
```

event listener:

```
public class Listener
{
    public void HandleProgressChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("event handled, waiting 2 seconds to continue");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

Program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Publisher p = new Publisher();
        Listener c = new Listener();
        p.ProgressChanged += c.HandleProgressChanged;

        Console.WriteLine(" --the regular way--");
        p.Run(2);

        // QUESTION 1:
        // execution of Run halts until its subscribers have processed the event. Why?
        // my intuition tells me the Run method should just do it's thing, uninterrupted
        // and any listeners should pick it up without affecting the publisher.
        // This is obviously too naive an understanding, but why?
        // Is this because the event raising method
        // waits for its subscribers to finish processing the event?
        // if so, why?

        Console.WriteLine("--the tasks way--");
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => p.Run(2)); // used a lambda to allow passing a parameter to Run

        // QUESTION 2:
        // execution of Run still halts until its subscribers have processed the event. Why?
        // it was assigned it's own task, so why does it still wait for it's listeners to finish? 

        // What I would like is to have the publisher run it's thing,
        // and have listeners respond to its events without disrupting the publisher

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

Comment: When you invoke an event, the handlers will execute on the same thread that invoked it. Is `handler.BeginInvoke(this, EventArgs.Empty,null,null);` closer to the behavior you expect?

Comment: @JonathonChase Yes! But why? What magic is this?

Comment: Calling the EventHandler's Invoke method (equivalent to `handler(sender,args)`) isn't asynchronous- you're essentially just dispatching a call to a delegate, so it's basically a normal method call. You may want to take a [look at this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916095/how-do-i-make-an-eventhandler-run-asynchronously)

Comment: Thank you, that simultaneously confirmed and confused my suspicion. You claim the Invoke and handler(..) are equivalent but they yield different results?

Comment: `handler(this, EventArgs.Empty)` is equivalent to `handler.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty)`. The results are different when you use `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: I'll read up on BeginInvoke. Thanks

Comment: You may want to read [this document series](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/event-based-asynchronous-pattern-eap) while you're at it, if you're going to use events for your asynchronous programming over TAP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184781/discussion-between-arno-van-boven-and-jonathon-chase).