# Control.Invoke() vs. Control.BeginInvoke()

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between Invoke() and BeginInvoke()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke)

First of all, I would like to apologize for my bad grammar since English is not my native tongue.

This is my understanding:

```
Control.Invoke(delegated_method)  // Executes on the thread wich the control was created on
witch holds its handle ,typically  this would be the main thread of a winform application .

Control.BeginInvoke(delegated_method // Executes asynchronously on a threadPool Thread .
```

According to MSDN, it says

> Executes a delegate asynchronously on
>   the thread that the control's
>   underlying handle was created on.

My QUESTION :

Am I to understand that beginInvoke treats the main thread in this matter as it would the thread pool, and execute the delegated method on the main thread when it "gets a chance" ?

Another question which is raised, 
is it possible to create a control not on the main thread ?
if so could someone give me an example?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke

Comment: Your grammar is better than a good majority of native english speakers; however, you need to go back and accept answers to some of your questions (hit the green checkmark next to the answer you think is best)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will be executed on the dispatcher of the UI thread that created it.

As for creating a control on a background thread, I wouldn't advise it. Furthermore, you haven't mentioned what technology you are working with.