# MethodInvoker vs Control.Invoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, invoke

I'm doing simple GUI updates on a timer.  Which method is better to use if i am updating a single control? MethodInvoker like this:

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
  systemMode.Text = systemMode.ToString();
});
```

or create a control invoke like this:

```
public void UpdateSystemMode()
{
    if (systemMode.InvokeRequired)
    {
         UpdateSystemMode.Invoke(new
             UpdateSystemModeDelegate(UpdateSystemMode));
    }
    else
    {
        systemMode.UpdateSystemMode();
    }  
}
```

Obviously, the method invoker has less code up front, but which one is best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UpdateSystemMode.Invoke(new UpdateSystemModeDelegate(UpdateSystemMode));`

and

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
{
  systemMode.Text = systemMode.ToString();
});
```

is absolutely same
as well as

```
this.Invoke((Action)(()=> systemMode.Text = systemMode.ToString()));
```

right way:

```
public void UpdateSystemMode()
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
         this.BeginInvoke((Action)UpdateSystemMode);
    else
        systemMode.UpdateSystemMode(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Your last line needed the first ';' removed, though.

Comment: Beware that `BeginInvoke` has different semantics than `Invoke`! And `Control.Invoke` is supposedly faster if you use the `MethodInvoker` delegate type rather than `Action`.

Comment: @Sven, what is the difference between Action and MethodInvoker for Invoke method? O_o they both are parameterless and have void as return type.

Comment: And yes, I know about difference between BeginInvoke and Invoke - BeginInvoke is less rough for perfomance :)

Comment: @Nagg - Are you saying the code with the BeginInvoke is the correct way to do it?  As i understand it, if i am going to update a bunch of GUI elements at once, I should just use the MethodInvoker instead.  Is this true?  The reason i ask is that i am running a very fast paced program and i need to keep performance optimal.  I will have about 30 GUI elements that need updating.  A chunk of them happens in one call, the rest may be piecemeal.

Comment: @Nagg: on paper they're the same, yeah, but the docs for `Control.Invoke` clearly state "A call to an EventHandler or MethodInvoker delegate will be faster than a call to another type of delegate." I guess there must be some internal optimizations with that particularly delegate type in mind.

Comment: @Jason, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke

Comment: @Jason, in short - by using BeginInvoke - your worker-thread will doesnt wait completion of delegated method

Comment: @Nagg - Thanks.  That was some good info.  The calls i'm making to update the GUI are called by another function asynchronously.  I'm using a BeginInvoke at that point, so i think i am able to continue on without any blocking.
Basically, I have my timer, and on the tick call myDelegate.BeginInvoke, which calls a function that uses the MethodInvoker