# Difficulty in understanding c# method description

Tags: c#

I was looking at [`Control.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke.aspx) method and I didn't quite get what it means when it says:

> Executes a delegate asynchronously on the thread that the control's
>   underlying handle was created on.

What is `control's underlying handle`? What does it do?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Controls have "thread affinity"  - meaning there is a *demand* that they are only *directly* manipulated (or even *inspected*, except a few specific properties such as `InvokeRequired`) by the thread that created them (commonly called the UI thread). The *handle* is simply the abstraction between the OS control and the .NET control.

What this actually does is place a message on the windows message loop, that is picked up by the UI thread (which owns the control), causing your delegate to be invoked on the UI thread. This means it is allowed to talk to the control. This is useful if you are currently on a background thread (maybe an async callback or `BackgroundWorker`), and need to update the UI.

Answer (score 1):

It means the windows handle - the internal, non managed reference to the control.

See [`Contorl.Handle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx):

> Gets the window handle that the control is bound to.

And:

> The value of the Handle property is a Windows HWND.

Comment: So is it equal to `Executes a delegate asynchronously on the thread that the control was created on.`

Comment: @LAS_VEGAS - That's my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Forms controls are created on a specific thread, and are not designed for use in multithreaded environments. Microsoft made it so that the control can only be manipulated from the thread it was created on, thus forcing a single threaded environment on the controls.

BeginInvoke on a control invokes the code supplied to it on that thread.