# What is the best/safest way to access the main UI thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety, dispatcher

I would like to know, what is the best/safest way to access the main UI thread from another thread.

Should i use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`?

```
_cancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        new Task(() =>
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    //process data
                }));
            }, _cancelationTokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Start();
```

or should i use `Dispatcher.Invoke`?

```
    _cancelationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        new Task(() =>
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                {
                    //process data
                }));
            }, _cancelationTokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning).Start();
```

What is the main difference between the 2 `Invoke` methods?

What will the performance impact be when using `BeginInvoke` and `Invoke`?

**Most important, i would like to keep my UI responsive.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke check this one

Comment: I guess you're reffering to the WPF, since it's quite different than winforms...

Comment: Do I get this right: You create a task for asynchronous execution, but in this task delegate the heavy calculation again to the UI thread. I'm wondering what you need a task for? Wouldn't you need to process data in the task and invoke the dispatcher only to update the UI? Otherwise you block the UI thread by whatever you do in `//process data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke() if you want to call it synchronous and BeginInvoke() for async .. if you use BeginInvoke you will need to pass the delegate to be called when the operation is finished.

You are already on a background thread so UI will remain responsive either way. Just depends on whether you want this thread's execution to wait for the operation to finish or if you want it done in the background while this thread's execution continues.