# Does Delegate.Invoke() start the method the delegate is pointed at on a new thread, or do you need to use Delegate.BeginInvoke()?

Tags: c#, delegates

Does Delegate.Invoke() start the method the delegate is pointed at on a new thread, or do you need to use Delegate.BeginInvoke() to do this?

Thanks

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegate.Invoke: Executes synchronously, on the same thread.
Delegate.BeginInvoke: Executes asynchronously, on a threadpool thread.

from the answer here - [What's the difference between Invoke() and BeginInvoke()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke)

Answer (score 0):

It runs on the same thread it is currently running, unless you do BeginInvoke

Answer (score 0):

`Delegate.Invoke()` is just like calling the delegate, which will cause calling the delegate on the same thread. To make an async call on the delegate, you have to call it with `BeginInvoke` which eventually will make the call on a different thread (and then activate the Callback method)