# Smartthreadpool how to know when all threads are done?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Im trying to figure out how to find out when all my `threads` in the queue are done.. when they are done i want to display a `MessageBox` saying something like "Operation completed".

This is the code i am using to queue my threads:

```
Smart.STPStartInfo stpStartInfo = new Smart.STPStartInfo();
stpStartInfo.MaxWorkerThreads = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown5.Value);
stpStartInfo.MinWorkerThreads = 2;
_smartThreadPool = new Smart.SmartThreadPool(stpStartInfo);

foreach (string item in urlQueue)
{
    _smartThreadPool.QueueWorkItem(
        new Amib.Threading.Func<string, int, int, string, int>(checkURLSmart),
                                item, iia, 5000, kryptonTextBox1.Text);

    iia++;
}
```

Any ideas how to know when all threads have completed their work?

Comment: What version of .NET and why use a (Smart) ThreadPool? Would Tasks (TPL) be usable?

Comment: Am using .NET 4.0. Not sure what TPL is :/

Comment: Duplicate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795439/smartthreadpool-blocking-ui-thread

Answer (score 0):

You can use WaitAll or WaitAny on a SmartThreadPool.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7933/Smart-Thread-Pool#Feature4

Comment: How would i do that without stopping the GUI?

Comment: You will have to do the waiting on yet another Thread or Task. Same as with my answer. And then use Control.Invoke to show the results.