# Lambda multiline as Thread parameter?

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, lambda, delegates

Time ago I've seen a multi-threading technique code like this:

```
Private Delegate Sub TextBoxUpdateUI(ByVal txt As String)

Private t As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(Sub() _
        If tb2.InvokeRequired Then 
            Dim tb_delegate As New TextBoxUpdateUI(AddressOf "This Sub")
            tb2.Invoke(tb_delegate, Text)
        Else
            tb2.Text = tb1.Text
        End If _
)
```

The thing is that, be able to write some instructions inside the Thread argument, I don't remember well the example that I've seen but if I remember well it used a `Lambda` like I've tried to use.

But the code above does not work, just I wanted to reproduce it, but I lost the example that I've seen so I don't know exactly how to write it.

Someone can fix the lambda?

Also, at the delegate line in the `AdressOf` operator how could I fix it to refer to that?

Comment: What about it isn't working?  Are you calling `t.Start()`?

Comment: @Steven Doggart with "isn't working" I mean that can't be compiled because an exception says that Lambda expression should have one line instance or something simillar message, sorry I can't verify the exception message now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two syntax styles for lambda expressions in VB.NET: single-line, and multi-line.  When you are doing a multi-line expression, you need to actually go to a new line immediately after the `Sub` or `Function` declaration.  If you don't, it will assume that it is a single-line expression.  So, the first problem is that you have a line continuation character after the `Sub() _` which means that the following `If` statement is on the same line as the `Sub` declaration, so it assumes it is a single-line expression.

The second problem is that when you are writing a multi-line lambda expression, you must end it with an `End Sub` or `End Function` statement.  Your code is missing that line.  So, to fix your code, just change it like this:

```
Private t As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(Sub()
        If tb2.InvokeRequired Then 
            Dim tb_delegate As New TextBoxUpdateUI(AddressOf "This Sub")
            tb2.Invoke(tb_delegate, Text)
        Else
            tb2.Text = tb1.Text
        End If
    End Sub
    )
```

It's worth mentioning, however, that this is a terrible example.  The only thing that the thread is doing, in this example, is invoking back to the UI thread, which is is, of course, single-threaded, so the extra thread is completely unnecessary.  If that's really all you are trying to do--invoke something on the UI thread, but not sit and wait for the UI to process the request--you should just use `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke`, like this (no new thread required):

```
If TextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
    TextBox1.BeginInvoke(Sub() TextBox1.Text = "sometext")
Else
    TextBox1.Text = "sometext"
End If
```

Comment: Thankyou, so, If I understanded good, the `Invoke` method invokes the action on the main thread, but `BeginInvoke` method creates a new thread or something simillar to run the action, I made ​​a mess, If I want to do a multi-threaded application then in the secondary threads I need to use `Invoke`, or I need to use `BeginInvoke`?

Comment: No matter I've found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke/

Comment: What about the `AdressOf` operator of this line inside the Lambda?: `Dim tb_delegate As New TextBoxUpdateUI(AddressOf "This Sub")` I would like to set the delegate inside the Lambda instead of doing this else: `tb2.BeginInvoke(Sub() tb2.Text = tb1.Text)`

Comment: I don't know how to get a delegate to the current lambda expression.  It would make a good new question.  But even if there is a way to do it, I wouldn't recommend it.  It would be ugly and confusing.  At that point, I'd just use an actual separate method rather than a multi-line lambda expression.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the thread or the delegate just

```
    If TextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
        TextBox1.Invoke(Sub() TextBox1.Text = "sometext")
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "sometext"
    End If
```

Comment: Hi, I know that I can use a Lmanda on the Invoke method, but I would to reproduce the technique that I've seen. Thanks for answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the `AddressOf` method to the `ParameterizedThreadStart` using Lambda.

You can also write the `TextBoxUpdateUi` method inline using sub(), but you have to declare
`TextBoxUpdateUI` delegate.

For example:

```
Delegate Sub TextBoxUpdateUI(ByVal text As String)
```

If you want it in Lambda it would be this way:

```
   Dim MyThread As New Thread( _
            New ParameterizedThreadStart( _
                Sub()
                    If tb2.InvokeRequired Then
                         Dim tb_delegate As New TextBoxUpdateUI(Sub(x)
                                                               'Do your stuff here
                                                               tb1.Text = x
                                                           End Sub)
                        tb2.Invoke(tb_delegate, Text)
                    Else
                        tb2.Text = tb1.Text
                    End If
                End Sub))
```