# Store a Lambda expression into a variable?

Tags: .net, vb.net, variables, lambda, expression

I don't know if this has much sense, I'm just experimenting things to extend my knowledge (which is not much).

Is it possibly to store a `Lambda` expression into a variable for later use it?

This is what I've tried:

```
Private t As Thread = New Thread(ThreadLambda)

Dim ThreadLambda As Expressions.LambdaExpression = _
    Sub()
        If tb2.InvokeRequired Then
            tb2.BeginInvoke(Sub() tb2.Text = tb1.Text)
        Else
            tb2.Text = tb1.Text
        End If
    End Sub
```

That launchs this exception:

> Lambda expression cannot be converted to
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression' because
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression' is not a delegate type.
>
> UPDATE:

I'm trying to follow @大师 燈 Xi Huan instructions but this Class is giving me a compiler exception of `InvalidOperationException`, it says that the value cannot be null (What value!?)

```
Public Class Form1

    Private t As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(ThreadLambda)

    Dim ThreadLambda As Threading.ThreadStart = _
        Sub()
            For x = 0 To 10 : Debug.WriteLine("test") : Next
        End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: `t` and `ThreadLambda` are both members of `Form1`. When you create an instance of `Form1`, `t` is created before `ThreadLambda`. At that point, `ThreadLambda` is `Nothing`. A simple fix is to declare `ThreadLambda` before `t`, or create `t` in the constructor of `Form1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.aspx) is a "ordinary" type, not a delegate type; but you can use [`System.Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/system.action.aspx), which is a delegate type:

```
Dim ThreadLambda As Action = _
    Sub()
        If tb2.InvokeRequired Then
            tb2.BeginInvoke(Sub() tb2.Text = tb1.Text)
        Else
            tb2.Text = tb1.Text
        End If
    End Sub
```

`Action` matches your lambda because it does not take arguments, and does not return a value.

---

If you want to use the [`Thread` constructor that accepts an parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xx3ezzs2.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) of the [`ThreadStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx) delegate type, use [`ThreadStart`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx) instead of `Action`:

```
Dim ThreadLambda As ThreadStart = _
    Sub()
        If tb2.InvokeRequired Then
            tb2.BeginInvoke(Sub() tb2.Text = tb1.Text)
        Else
            tb2.Text = tb1.Text
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thankyou, but then how to use the action here?: `Private t As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(ThreadLambda)`

Comment: `Threading.Thread` expects a `ThreadStart`; since `ThreadStart` also does not expect any parameters nor a return value, you can declare `ThreadLambda` as `Dim ThreadLambda As ThreadStart = ...`

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how I could use the Lambda Action into the declared thread, I can replace the `ThreadLambda` word here: New Thread(`ThreadLambda`) to write all the lambda code and it will works, then how I can use there the Action that you've helped me to store the Lambda?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. You can store your lambda expression in a variable like `Dim ThreadLambda As ThreadStart = Sub() ...whatever...` and later create a thread with `Private t As Thread = New Thread(ThreadLambda)`.

Comment: Now I've understood, but the ThreadStart is giving me a compiler exception, please could you see my update?

Comment: `t` and `ThreadLambda` are both members of `Form1`. When you create an instance of `Form1`, `t` is created before `ThreadLambda`. At that point, `ThreadLambda` is `Nothing`. A simple fix is to declare `ThreadLambda` before `t`, or create `t` in the constructor of `Form1`

Comment: That is almost the same I answered to you yesterday... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19492251/lambda-multiline-as-thread-parameter/19494433#19494433

Comment: @CarlosLanderas While related, that question was different. It was about the OP not knowing how to create multiline lamda expressions, while this question is about assigning lambda expressions to a variable.

Comment: Because the Sub() End Sub() it's a delegate. And an Action is a delegate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376657/what-is-the-difference-between-delegate-action-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

A LambdaExpression is NOT a lambda. It is an expression that, when processed, will create a lambda. The same goes for any type of expression, not just lambda expressions. Check [Why would you use Expression> rather than Func?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/793571/why-would-you-use-expressionfunct-rather-than-funct) for more.

A Lambda's actual type is either Action<> or Func<>, depending on whether it returns a result or not. The rest of the type arguments are the lambda's parameters.

So, for example this creates a lambda function that adds to numbers:

```
Func<int,int,int> f= (a,b)=>a+b;
var res1=f(5,4);
var res2=f(3,7);
```

While this creates a lambda that writes to the console:

```
Action<string> g= (txt)=>Console.WriteLine(txt);
g("This is a message);
```

BTW, you should consider using the newer Task methods to run your lambda instead of a naked thread, eg:

```
Task.Run(theLambda);
```

Comment: Thankyou but it says that Run is not a member of Tasks, I'm on FW 4.0

Comment: Then it's [Task.Factory.StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321439.aspx) with overloads that accept either actions or functions

Comment: *A LambdaExpression is NOT a lambda. It is an expression...* No, `LambdaExpression` is a type that represents a lambda expression, not an expression itself.

Comment: *A Lambda's actual type is either Action<> or Func<>* No, you can assign lambda expressions to other delegate types than `Action<>` and `Func<>`, as long as the signature fits.

Comment: @大师燈XiHuan a LambdaExpression [inherits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.aspx) from Expression. So it IS an expression for all intents and purposes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Just because it inherits from a class that is called `Expression` does not make it an expression from the language's point of view. The way you wrote your answer is ambiguous. The fact that there's a type called `LambdaExpression` that the OP uses in his question is orthogonal to the fact C# supports lambda expressions. You can't just assign a lambda expression (the language construct) to a `LambdaExpression` (the type) variable. That's the problem of the OP.