# How to display message to use synchronously while dispatcher processing is suspended?

Tags: wpf, dispatcher, wpf-4.0

when application raises some exception, normally what is done is, exception is logged, displayed to user, and based on its severity, we continue to use app or close it.

In case of some exceptions, like

"Cannot perform this operation while dispatcher processing is suspended."

exception, where UI cannot display message to user, we need to use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to asynchronously show the message to user. The problem with BeginInvoke is that it returns immediately and code continues to execute where from the point it showed message box. In cases where we require user input (like Yes / No dialogs).

So, how can we safely show the message box **dialog**, and still wait for the user resulting action, before we continue with code execution?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Invoke()` instead of `BeginInoke()` your thread will not immediately return until the task has been completed, allowing you to ask for user input on how to proceed.

More information in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/229554/1316346) question

Comment: It is not possible to use Invoke when Dispatcher processing is suspended.

Comment: @Goran Ah I see, would it be possible to `BeginInvoke` not only the message box, but the remainder of the code you would like to run as well without requiring a lot of retooling of what you already have?

Comment: Well, that would require complete code to be marked as async, since I can not really tell when an exception will happen (unhandled). :)