# Serial port latch Application C#

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

I'm making an application that is reading the serial port and updating data in a WindowsForms application screen.

Sometimes when you try to close the program is locked. 
I'm using delegate.

What should I be doing wrong?

```
void sp1_LineReceived(object sender, LineReceivedEventArgs Args)
{
  Invoke(new Action(() =>
  {
    // execute code
  }));
}
```

Init

```
public FormPrincipal()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  spSistema.LineReceived += new LineReceivedEventHandler(sp1_LineReceived);
  // next codes
}
```

Outher codes

```
public partial class FormPrincipal : Form
{       
  SerialPort spSimulador = new SerialPort();        
  public static PortaSerial spSistema = new PortaSerial();
```

Comment: Are you properly closing the serial port on exit?

Comment: It is very likely to cause deadlock when you use the Close() method while the device is sending.  Use BeginInvoke() or remove Close() or run Close on a worker thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `BeginInvoke` is preferable to `Invoke`, as it won't block. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke). You may well have a deadlock here.

```
void sp1_LineReceived(object sender, LineReceivedEventArgs Args)
{
  BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
  {
    // execute code
  }));
}
```