# Thread to giu delegates with variable number of parameters

Tags: c#, multithreading, parameters, delegates

I have found several posts about delegates with variable number of parameters but I'm too thick to understand what they mean and how they apply to my situation.

This is what I have in the main form:

```
public delegate void Report( params Object[] args );
...

public partial class Main : Form
{
    public ReportDelegate m_dlgtReport;
    ...

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        m_dlgtReport = new ReportDelegate( this.Report );
        ...
    }

    private void Report( params Object[] args )
    {
        if( args.Length > 0 )
        {
            string s1 = (string)args[ 0 ];
        }
        ...
    }
```

This is how I call this from a thread:

```
m_Main.Invoke(
    m_Main.m_dlgtReport,
    new Object[] {
        "text",
        101,
        true
        } );

m_Main.Invoke(
    m_Main.m_dlgtReport,
    new Object[] {
        "text"
        } );
```

The compiler goes for it but the application crashes.

Anyone out there could either speak really, really slow to me or simply fix the code above and I'll study it?

Thank you all, kind people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to write:

```
this.Invoke(m_dlgtReport, (Object) new Object[] { "text", 101, true });
```

The important part being the cast to (Object).

Comment: No loathing of you, my friend. You are my favorite person of the day.

Comment: Thanks! By the way, most times you should use BeginInvoke instead of Invoke.  E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke

Comment: Brilliant. That's just brilliant.