# C# winforms GUI will not accept data from other threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Below is a function I have running in a while(true) loop in a thread running a Winforms GUI.
I have a button set to put text data into the inBuffer object. this always works, however when I place into the buffer object from a different thread, the data is detected, pulled, and printed out in the Console.out.WriteLine statement, however it never shows up in the Display (textBox) object

```
public void put()
    {   
        string strDisplayMe = ModemKind.MainClass.inBuffer.MkRequest();
        if (strDisplayMe != "")
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("FOUND SOMETHING IN BUFFER: " + strDisplayMe);
            char[] DisplayMeArr = strDisplayMe.ToCharArray ();
            for (int i = 0; i <= DisplayMeArr.Length -1; ++i) 
            {
                this.display.Text += DisplayMeArr [i];
                Thread.Sleep (100);
            }
        this.display.Text += '\n';
        }
    }
```

EDIT: this is a separate class from what is feeding it data through the static buffer objects

Comment: Look at `Invoke()`, i.e. `this.display.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {this.display.Text += DisplayMeArr [i];});`

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at the following question? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Only the main window thread can access/change controls... if you want update the UI from the thread that runs the loop, you need to sync the call with the main thread using the `Control.Invoke` method.

For instance...

```
public void put()
{   
    string strDisplayMe = ModemKind.MainClass.inBuffer.MkRequest();
    if (strDisplayMe != string.Empty)
    {
        char[] DisplayMeArr = strDisplayMe.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i <= DisplayMeArr.Length -1; ++i) 
        {
            this.UpdateUI(() => { this.display.Text += DisplayMeArr[i]; });
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }

        this.UpdateUI(() => { this.display.Text += '\n'; });
    }
}

private void UpdateUI(Action handler)
{
    this.Invoke(handler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use MethodInvoker to access TextBox from other thread then GUI thread. Make a method to access the `TextBox` using [MethodInvoker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker(v=vs.110).aspx). you are assigning text multiple times consider assigning it once for performance, and use `StringBuilder` for string concatenation.

```
public void put()
{   
    string strDisplayMe = ModemKind.MainClass.inBuffer.MkRequest();
    if (strDisplayMe != "")
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("FOUND SOMETHING IN BUFFER: " + strDisplayMe);
        char[] DisplayMeArr = strDisplayMe.ToCharArray ();
        for (int i = 0; i <= DisplayMeArr.Length -1; ++i) 
        {
            AssignToTextBox(this.display, this.display.Text + DisplayMeArr [i]);
            Thread.Sleep (100);
        }
    AssignToTextBox(this.display, this.display.Text +  '\n');
    }
}

void AssignToTextBox(TextBox txtBox, string value)
{
  if(txtBox.InvokeRequired)
  {
      txtBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { txtBox.text = value;      }));
  }
}
```

**Edit** You can use `BeginInvoke` instead of Invoke to call it asynchronously. Read more about the `Invoke` and `BeginInvoke` in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke).

```
void AssignToTextBox(TextBox txtBox, string value)
{
      txtBox.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>txtBox.Text = value ));
}
```

Comment: This seems great but I am unsure of what you are referring to by txtFolderName.

Comment: Actually, the Thread.Sleep seems to be part of a "slow modem connection" effect :D