# C# BackgroundWorker and Invoke

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker, invoke

Can someone explain why invoking `Thread.Sleep` from `BackgroundWorker` blocks its execution. Invoke should cause the delegate to be executed on the UI thread and background thread should continue with execution. But that does not happen - why?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BackgroundWorker bgrw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bgrw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgrw_DoWork);

        bgrw.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void bgrw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); })); //should be executed on the UI thread
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now); // This line is executed after 2 seconds
    }       
}
```

Comment: "Invoke should cause the delegate to be executed on the UI thread" - yes - "and background thread should continue" - no. Look at the definition for [`Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) and note that it's return value is whatever the delegate returned. It can't return that value to you until the code has completed executing. `Invoke` blocks.

Comment: Why not just call Thread.Sleep() from the UI Thread right after you started your Backgroundworker ?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/229558/4112271

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a rather simple explanation. `Invoke` is a *blocking call*. If you want to queue work on the UI message loop asynchronously, use [`BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

> Executes the specified delegate **asynchronously** on the thread that the
>   control's underlying handle was created on.

```
void bgrw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { Thread.Sleep(2000); })); 
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
}
```

Note your code, as currently constructed makes no sense. I'm assuming you're using this for testing purposes.