# How to remove children from with another thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, parent-child

mycode :

```
        Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();
>       Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle();

>                  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
>                  {
>                         while(true)
>                          {
>                             myCanvas.Children.Clear();
>                            //do something
>                            for(int i=1;i<=100;i++)
>                            {
>                               myCanvas.Children.Add(myRectangle[i]);
>                            }
                           }
>                  }).ContinueWith(t =>
>                  {
> 
>                  }, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None,
>                  TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

I still got error : "Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget." what i should do?

Comment: This has nothing to do with threading. You are trying to add a control to the canvas when the control is already added to another container. A visual control in WPF cannot have more than one parent.

Comment: This happens because of the _while(true)_ part in the second loop, when the visual is already in CanvasX.

Comment: sorry please read again. I forgot add thread.

Comment: no have canvasX i edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use *Dispatcher.Invoke* method.

```
while (true)
{
     Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { myCanvas.Children.Clear(); }));
     for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
     {
         Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { myCanvas.Children.Add(myRectangle[i]); }));
     }
}
```

Note that *Invoke* blocks the calling thread.

Comment: It's work!! Thank you very much.
excuse me can you explain to me what different invoke and begininvoke ?

Comment: When you use Invoke, the calling thread waits for completion. This is not true for BeginInvoke. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke) or google it for other explanations.