# I can't invoke an SQL command on multiple threads C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, multithreading

So i have a method that does an invoke on a datagridview and works fine for the first thread that runs it, however when a second thread tries to utilise the method, the download part of it still functions, however the invoke statement stops working for the first thread and starts to change both

```
public void ByteTransferResume(int indexResume)
{
    HttpWebRequest req;
    HttpWebResponse resp;
    req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(FileLocationName);
    req.AddRange((int)fileInfoDestination.Length);
    resp = (HttpWebResponse)(req.GetResponse());
    long fileLength = resp.ContentLength;
    FileLocationLength = fileLength;
    using (Stream responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
    {
        int iBufferSize = 1024;
        iBufferSize *= 1000;
        using (FileStream saveFileStream = new FileStream(FileDestination, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            int iByteSize;
            byte[] downBuffer = new byte[iBufferSize];

            while ((iByteSize = responseStream.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                saveFileStream.Write(downBuffer, 0, iByteSize);

                FileInfo fileInfoDestinations = new FileInfo(FileDestination);

                FileDestinationLength = (int)fileInfoDestinations.Length;

                double downloadProgress = ((double)FileDestinationLength / FileLocationLength) * 100;

                // MessageBox.Show(downloadProgress.ToString());

                dgvDownloadInfo.Invoke(new dgvCommandDelegate(DGVCommand), new object[] { $"UPDATE Download_Info SET [Progress] = '{downloadProgress:F2}%' WHERE [File Name] = '{thread1[indexResume].Name}'" });

                //MessageBox.Show(thread1[indexResume].Name);
                //MessageBox.Show(indexResume.ToString());
                // dgvDownloadInfo.Invoke(new dgvConnectionDelegate(DGVConnection));
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding Lock() statement?

Comment: I'm not familiar with lock statements?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 Management Studio

Comment: Is dgvDownloadInfo a control?  If so [surely you want .BeginInvoke()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke)

Comment: nope didnt make any difference

Comment: It's been a while since I did C#, but can't you add [Serializable] above the block of code? Might be what you're looking for.

Comment: What is FileDestination? If it is a shared variable, you're overriding the file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you:

```
 public object _lock = new object();
 public void ByteTransferResume(int indexResume)
 {
     lock (_lock)
     {
         HttpWebRequest req;
         //rest of your method         
     }
  }
```

Comment: it didnt work im afraid, thanks anyway, sorry to be a pain im very new to this but i appreciate it all guys :) ill get there eventually!! :)