# Trying to get data from datepicker and textbox using a timer event

Tags: c#, wpf, events, timer

I am trying to get the data from a 'DatePicker' called `targetDate` and a couple of 'TextBox' called `targetHour` and `targetMinute`. I want to read whatever is in them every second. So I created a timer as follows:

```
System.Timers.Timer tmr = null;
private void SetTimer()
{
    tmr = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    tmr.AutoReset = true;
    tmr.Elapsed += TimerEvent;
    tmr.Enabled = true;
}
```

The timer is running fine and I am getting the data as well. For now, just for verification purposes I am displaying whatever I get from the `targetDate`, `targetHour` and `targetMinute` to another TextBox `differenceTime` inside the `TimerEvent`.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => targetDT = targetDate.Text));
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => targethh = Int32.Parse(targetHour.Text)));
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => targetmm = Int32.Parse(targetMinute.Text)));
//temp = targetDT + " " + targethh + ":" + targetMinute;
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() => differenceTime.Text = targetDT + "-" + targethh));
```

The above code is working ok. My main question is, is there a better way to do this, without using the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`? Also, but less important, if I try to use the `temp` string to populate `differenceTime` it doesn't work, why is that?

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε it is WPF

Comment: You can wrap all this code in a single `BeginInvoke` and `temp` will also start working then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My main question is, is there a better way to do this, without using the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`?

Either replace the `System.Timers.Timer` with a `DispatcherTimer` as suggested by @Jeff R and handle its `Tick` event. Then the code inside your `Tick` event handler will always be executed on the UI thread which means that you can access the controls directly.

You could also improve your current code by only calling `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` once:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    targetDT = targetDate.Text;
    targethh = Int32.Parse(targetHour.Text);
    targetmm = Int32.Parse(targetMinute.Text);
    differenceTime.Text = targetDT + "-" + targethh;
}));
```

> Also, but less important, if I try to use the temp string to populate differenceTime it doesn't work, why is that?

Because `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` returns before the delegate that you pass to it has been executed on the UI thread. You probably want to use `Dispatcher.Invoke` instead.

[What's the difference between Invoke() and BeginInvoke()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke)

Comment: doesnt work means that the temp string is empty, nothing in it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using WPF correct?

Then try using a `System.Windows.Timer.DispatcherTimer` instead of the `System.Timers.Timer`. The `DispatcherTimer` will run on the UI thread so may not be as accurate to the ms but won't require all the `BeginInvoke` calls.