# Cancel a loop in a task from outside

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

On a WinForm, I need to continuously read data from a source (USB device in my case) and display the data in labels. The reading should started on command (button_click) and stopped on another button click or in the form_closing method. I meanwhile found out that I need to use `Task.Factory` for this since I can create a `CancellationToken` there. Here is my (example) code so far:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    CancellationTokenSource m_CancellationSource;
    Task m_USBReaderTask;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        m_CancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        m_USBReaderTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => doAsync(m_CancellationSource.Token), m_CancellationSource.Token);
    }

    private void doAsync(CancellationToken ct)
    {
        InitUSBReader();
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            int[] data=ReadUSB();
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                lbOut1.Text = data[0].ToString();
                lbOut2.Text = data[1].ToString();
                lbOut3.Text = data[2].ToString();
                //... and so on...
            });
        }
        CleanupUSBReader(); //this is never happening
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (null != m_CancellationSource)
        {
            m_CancellationSource.Cancel();
            m_USBReaderTask.Wait(); // this always hangs.
        }
    }

}
```

Obviously I am facing two problems:

1. When the `CancellationToken` is set the task is aborted but I need to
   clean up, I just want to end the 'while' loop. (or does it crash and no error message?)
2. In the `FormClosing` event, I need to wait until the cleaning up has
   finished but it blocks endlessly.

Beside my two problems, is my approach correct at all or is there a more elegant way to achieve my goals?
Thanks

Comment: The task is **not** aborted. You have to code how the task will handle the cancellation request from the token

Comment: If you post a compilable source i'll help you

Comment: _"When the cancellatontoken is set the task is aborted"_ - pretty sure it's just flagged that you would like it to end. Don't think of it as `Thread.Abort`.  The actual code must regularly check `IsCancellationRequested` for a graceful exit or `.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` for semi-graceful.  You really need to show what `and so on` is doing because for all we know you are calculating PI to 10,000 places.

Comment: I guess `ReadUSB()` is a blocking method, if it doesn't return the task never finished. You have to make it cancellable. Another problem is race condition if you attempt to invoke when `FormClosing` is running, the invoke can't occur until event handler ends while event handler is waiting for invoke = deadlock. Using async invoke may help.

Comment: Why have you named the method `doAsync` like this? It is not an asynchronous method ( it does not return a `Task`).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: when I called the method doAsync, I just want to make clear that it runs as a separat thread that is not the UI thread. Does it need to be a Task?

Comment: @MickyD: The code does check the IsCancellationRequest in the while statement. I set a brakepoint in front of the cleanup call which was never reached.

Comment: Yeap, if it doesn't return a `Task` (or other awaitable type) you shouldn't give it the `Async` suffix, because it may create confusion to anyone reading your code. You may want to check out the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types), to get an idea why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first issue. When the token is canceled the While-loop will end, and the `CleanupUSBReader()` method should be run. This is assuming ReadUSB returns regularly, if not you will need some way to cancel the read. If you only cancel the task when the form is closing, the issue is probably a deadlock, see second paragraph. If the ReadUSB returns, you do not deadlock, and you still do not reach the cleanup method, there has to be some other issue, like an exception somewhere.

Regarding your second issue. The problem is that you call `this.Invoke`, this is synchronous, i.e. it will run the code on the main thread, and wait for it to complete. So when the form is closing the main thread asks the task to be cancelled and waits for it to complete, but the task is waiting for the main thread to update the UI. This result in a classing deadlock. One solution should be to use `this.BeginInvoke`, since this asks the main thread to update the UI, but does not wait for the result. Read more in [Invoke vs BeginInvoke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229554/whats-the-difference-between-invoke-and-begininvoke)

There is a general recommendation to avoid using `task.Wait()` since this very easily results in deadlocks like this. It might be a good idea to skip waiting for the task if the form is closing. Or to cancel the closing, `await` the task, and close the form after the await..

Comment: Dear Jonas, THANKS A LOT! Changing to BeginnInvoke solved both problems: Apparently the doAsync was terminated because of a crash in the Invoked part when called in the closing event, so the cleanup call was never reached. And waiting for an already terminated task takes endless. After changing to BeginnInvoke, I run in another problem: a DisconnectedContext error appeared. I could get around it by inserting a Thread.Sleep(1) brake into the loop but is there another (proper) way to prevent this?

Comment: @M. Enke I would suggest posting it as a new question

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways you could refactor your code, in order to avoid using the ugly `this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate` technique. If the USB reader is free threaded, you can invoke each of its methods in different `ThreadPool` threads, like this:

```
async Task LoopAsync(CancellationToken ct)
{
    await Task.Run(() => InitUSBReader(), ct);
    while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        int[] data = await Task.Run(() => ReadUSB(), ct);
        lbOut1.Text = data[0].ToString();
        lbOut2.Text = data[1].ToString();
        lbOut3.Text = data[2].ToString();
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
    await Task.Run(() => CleanupUSBReader(), ct);
}
```

But if the USB reader requires thread affinity, then the above method will not work. To make it run in a single thread, you could use the technique bellow, which also offers the advantage of decoupling the UI code from the USB reading code:

```
Task LoopAsync(IProgress<int[]> progress, CancellationToken ct)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        InitUSBReader();
        while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            int[] data = ReadUSB();
            progress.Report(data);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
        CleanupUSBReader();
    }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

...and start the task like this:

```
m_USBReaderTask = LoopAsync(new Progress<int[]>(data =>
{
    lbOut1.Text = data[0].ToString();
    lbOut2.Text = data[1].ToString();
    lbOut3.Text = data[2].ToString();
}), m_CancellationSource.Token);
```

The [`Progress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1) class is normally used for reporting progress, but it is capable of reporting any kind of data.

For cleaning up when the form closes, you can handle the `FormClosing` event like this:

```
private async void Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!m_USBReaderTask.IsCompleted)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Enabled = false;
        m_CancellationSource.Cancel();
        await m_USBReaderTask;
        await Task.Yield(); // Ensure the asynchronous completion before Close
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the Progress class is an interesting approach. I always thought I need use a delegate to access UI controls...

Comment: @M.Enke Yeap, the `this.Invoke` is the old way of communication with the UI thread from background threads. Nowadays the preferred way is considered the async-await. It is easier to read and write. Regarding the `Progress` class, keep in mind that it behaves like the `BeginInvoke`, and it is not possible to make it behave like the `Invoke`. The background code continues immediately after calling the `Report` method, without waiting for the UI updates to occur. This is why I added the `Thread.Sleep(100)`, the avoid bombarding the UI with more progress notifications than it can handle.