# Naming commands in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, naming-conventions, icommand

Not having english as my primary language, I often question grammar when naming methodes and properties.

I use `NextCommand` as name for my command, `NextCommandExecuted` for the execution method and `CanNextCommand` for the status.

Does this make sense, or is there a more correct naming convention I should use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your suggested names `NextCommandExecuted` sounds/seems like the `command` has been executed or it has `completed its execution` which sounds a bit incorrect to me.

I would prefer

`NextCommand`

`NextCommandExecute`

and

`CanNextCommandExecute`

Answer (score 4):

The question is what does the NextCommand?

If it moves to a next element in a list, then i would prefer **MoveToNextCommand** as name for the command. **CanMoveToNext** for the method to check if the command can be executed and **MoveToNext** for the method that executes the command.

Answer (score 0):

I use `NextCommand`, `NextCommandExecuted` and `NextCommandCanExecute`

Answer (score -1):

I usually do like follows:

```
NextCommand

OnNextCommand

OnCanNextCommand
```

Comment: Shouldn't the On... convention be used for event-raisers? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724085/events-naming-convention-and-style

Comment: I use On__ for both event raisers and commands. Just like 'On' for brevity.

Comment: These On...'s are not commands but they are handlers. Which can cause confusion (apparently)