# How to declare asynchronous event Action type in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, blazor, blazor-server-side

The injectable service is actually working like this:

```
public event Action<TValue1, TValue2, TValue3> OnAddChange;
public void AddReport(TValue1 var1, TValue2 var2, TValue3 var3)
{
    NotifyAddChanged(var1, var2, var3);
}
private void NotifyAddChanged(TValue1 var1, TValue2 var2, TValue3 var3)
{
    OnAddChange?.Invoke(var1, var2, var3);
}
```

And the consumer goes like this:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    MyService.OnAddChange+= addToList;
}

public void Dispose()
{
    MyService.OnAddChange -= addToList;
}

private void addToList(TValue1 variable1, TValue2 variable2, TValue3 variable3)
{
}
```

But I came to a point where my event must be asynchronous.
I tried different approach like `public Task event Action<TValue1, TValue2, TValue3> OnAddChange;`, but it isn't working.
So, how can I make it asynchronous?

Comment: Specify how and why you 'need it async', maybe this should be reopened.

Comment: As a side note, the name `OnAddChange` [is not suitable for an event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724085/events-naming-convention-and-style). The `On` prefix is generally reserved for the `protected virtual` method that raises the event.

Comment: Check this out: [How do I await events in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27761852/how-do-i-await-events-in-c) You probably need to declare the event as `public event Func<TValue1, TValue2, TValue3, Task> AddChange`.