# "System.InvalidOperationException: The object is currently in use elsewhere" - how do I resolve this?

Tags: c#, exception, invoke

I got this error when trying to update an image.
It was a cross-thread update, but I used .Invoke(), so that shouldn't be the problem, should it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(Answering my own question, for others, and for future reference)*

I *think* (not yet entirely sure) that this is because InvokeRequired will always return false if the control has not yet been loaded/shown. I have done a workaround which seems to work for the moment, which is to simple reference the handle of the associated control in its creator, like so:

```
var x = this.Handle;
```

(See http://ikriv.com:8765/en/prog/info/dotnet/MysteriousHang.html - down? [cached version](http://209.85.129.132/search?q=cache:www.ikriv.com/en/prog/info/dotnet/MysteriousHang.html))

(Related question: [Boiler plate code replacement - is there anything bad about this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192980/boiler-plate-code-replacement-is-there-anything-bad-about-this-code))

Answer (score 3):

If the handle doesn't yet exist, you can force it by subclassing the control and calling `CreateHandle`; however, the bigger question is: why are you doing things with a form that hasn't been loaded? Personally  I'd only start such an operation after Load.

Comment: The form is loaded, but these are controls which are dynamically loaded into a user control which is not yet set to Visible=true, (I think).