# Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, winforms, invoke

I am executing following code:

```
grid.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf RefreshDataSource))
```

getting `InvalidOperationException` exception.

Message: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method)
   at DataForm.BindData() in D:\Proj\DataForm.vb:line 380
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.PrivateProcessMessage(RuntimeMethodHandle md, Object[] args, Object server, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
```

Comment: Do you call Invoke in the Form constructor?

Comment: no, it is not in the constructor

Comment: Please show more code - where is the invoke called from ?

Comment: It is inside a method that is getting invoked on occurrence of an event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808867/invoke-or-begininvoke-cannot-be-called-on-a-control-until-the-window-handle-has)

Comment: <sigh> *what* event?

Answer (score 0):

Change the call from the load event to form.shown event to ensure that the control has been created first

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!this.IsHandleCreated)
    this.CreateControl();

this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
       //do so      
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this before you call the invoke method  `while (!this.IsHandleCreated) 
                          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)`