# Cross-thread operation not valid, control accessed from thread other than the thread it was created on

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am getting an error `"Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'AllOtherStatus' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."`

I have this code: `_output` is set to `AllOtherStatus`, looking at the debugger, `_output.InvokeRequired` is `false`

This code was working fine until I changed an unrelated class which doesn't use this piece of code. Code gets to the else statement then throws the exception.

```
private void Thread(Object p)
        {
        lock (this)
            {
            if (_output.InvokeRequired)
                {
                if(s!= null)
                    _output.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { _output.AppendText(s); }));
                }
            else
                _output.AppendText(s);

            s = null;
            }
        }
```

So my question is why is `_output.InvokeRequired` suddenly returning false when it should clearly be returning true?

Comment: What type of control is `AllOtherStatus` and where is it being created?

Comment: It is a `TextBox`, it's being created with windows forms in the `InitializeComponent();` The first line of code under `MainForm`

Comment: No, at least I don't think so. It was created using the designer in windows forms.

Comment: Do you still get an error if you comment out `lock(this)`?

Comment: Yes, I still get the same error

Comment: You should virtually never be using `InvokeRequired`.  Either you're calling this method from a non-UI thread an you *know* you need to invoke, in which case why check, or it's already in the UI thread and you don't need to call `Invoke`.  You shouldn't put yourself in the position in which you genuinely don't know, and in the rare case that you do, you can call `Invoke` anyway as it will work even if you're already in the UI thread.  The use of `InvokeRequired` only adds problems, it doesn't solve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN documentation -

> InvokeRequired can return false if Invoke is not required (the call
>   occurs on the same thread), or if the control was created on a
>   different thread but the control's handle has not yet been created.
>
> In the case where the control's handle has not yet been created, you
>   should not simply call properties, methods, or events on the control.
>   This might cause the control's handle to be created on the background
>   thread, isolating the control on a thread without a message pump and
>   making the application unstable.
>
> You can protect against this case by also checking the value of
>   IsHandleCreated when InvokeRequired returns false on a background
>   thread. If the control handle has not yet been created, you must wait
>   until it has been created before calling Invoke or BeginInvoke.
>   Typically, this happens only if a background thread is created in the
>   constructor of the primary form for the application (as in
>   Application.Run(new MainForm()), before the form has been shown or
>   Application.Run has been called.

It might be possible that unrelated code change defer the creation of handle for control. Can you check by explicitly creating handle before checking invoke required -

```
var handle = this.Handle;
if (_output.InvokeRequired)
{
  .....
}
```

Refer to the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808867/invoke-or-begininvoke-cannot-be-called-on-a-control-until-the-window-handle-has). They might be of your interest.

Comment: I set the textbox to have text immediately after creation, that solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

use this on form load or some where else before thread execution

```
     Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = False
```