# System.InvalidOperationException: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created

Tags: vb.net

Whenever we close our application, there is an unhandled exception being raised that doesn't give us much detail on it's root cause:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.BeginInvoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
at System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Post(SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)
at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.ConnectionPointCookie.Finalize()}
```

I don't see anywhere in our code where we're calling BeginInvoke.

We are calling Invoke but only if InvokeRequired = True.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

Comment: Duplicate of [Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808867/invoke-or-begininvoke-cannot-be-called-on-a-control-until-the-window-handle-has)

Comment: I tried the things on that page and it didn't help. Plus, that user had their own SafeInvoke method, I don't have anything like that.

Comment: The root cause is you using a WebBrowser in your code that you don't dispose.

Comment: We don't use a WebBrowser control in our code but we do have some WebRequests, is that what you meant?