# Unable to set label value in winforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, wcf

I'm trying to display a message in a label which is coming from a WCF callback. My label is in a windows form application.
The problem is the label isn't getting set when the callback is fired. I tried to use a Message Box instead of label and it works. There is nothing much of code to show. Here is the callback function.

```
    public void GetData(string message)
    {
        label1.Text = message;      // This doesn't work
        MessageBox.Show(message);   // This works fine
    }
```

Can anyone tell why a label is not getting set inside a callback function.

Comment: Try label1.Refresh(); after setting the text. Refresh causes the control to invalidate, and then update (i.e. immediately repaint itself).

Comment: Is the label dynamic if so is it added to your Form's control collection ? Try using a breakpoint, step through your method checking your variables.

Answer (score 0):

The call back event is fired on *non-GUI* thread and you can access *GUI* controls in GUI thread who created them. You can use Control.Invoke with MethodInvoker to access control (`label`) in callback event handler.

```
public void GetData(string message)
{
    label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
    {
         label1.Text = message;     
    });
    MessageBox.Show(message);   
}
```

Comment: modified as you asked. But not it throws the following error `Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created.`

Comment: Are you calling Web service in constructor if so then call it in form load

Comment: Actually, `GetData` is a WCF callback function inside a windows desktop app which is triggered asynchronously by the WCF service. I can't call it in form load.

Comment: From where you call that web service? also check this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808867/invoke-or-begininvoke-cannot-be-called-on-a-control-until-the-window-handle-has