# Update BindingList(of T) from different thread vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, multithreading, bindinglist

I have been looking for BindingList Invoke from other thread few days ago but not able to get a proper solution in vb.net , most of them are in C# but i am finding difficult to understand that.
Hence i have created a small application which has 2 Forms (Form1 and Form2) and one Class, Form1 will be main UI thread and Form2 will be running on a different thread.

Form1 has a DataGrindView bound to shared BindingList(of T) and a Button, once the Button clicked Form2 will be loaded on a different thread.

Here is  Form1 Codes :

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Threading
Public Class Form1
    Public Shared ListOfNames As BindingList(Of Names) = New BindingList(Of Names)

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        DataGridView1.DataSource = ListOfNames
        DataGridView1.Columns("FullName").DataPropertyName = "FullName"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim thread As Threading.Thread = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf loadQuoteForm)
        thread.SetApartmentState((ApartmentState.STA))
        thread.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub loadQuoteForm()
        Dim SecondForm As Form2 = New Form2
        Application.Run(SecondForm)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Form2 just has a button, once clicked will create a Names class instance , change its one property and try to add to Form1.BindingList(of T).

Here is Form2 Codes:

```vb
Public Class Form2
    Private Sub btnTestFromDiffTread_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTestFromDiffTread.Click
        Try
            Dim myName As Names = New Names
            myName.FullName = "John Peter"
            Form1.ListOfNames.Add(myName)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class


Imports System.ComponentModel
Public Class Names
    Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    Private _fullName As String
    Public Property FullName() As String
        Get
            Return _fullName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _fullName = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("FullName"))
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

but as you may have guessed as soon as button clicked on Form2 throws exception : 
[image]
.

Can anyone please suggest where i should invoke or delegate , sample VB.net codes are very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is updating of the DataGridView that is causing the issue.

From your comment I can see it is because the DataGridView is bound to DataSource of the DataGridView, so updating this List will cause a cross thread operation if you are doing this on a separate thread.

One solution is to not make `ListOfNames` public and have a new method to allow adding to this list:

```vb
Private Shared ListOfNames As BindingList(Of Names) = New BindingList(Of Names)

Public Sub AddNameToList(newNames As Names)
    DataGridView1.BeginInvoke(Sub() ListOfNames.Add(newNames))
End Sub
```

Comment: No, it still shows error after doing suggested fix : - "System.InvalidOperationException: Cross-thread operation not valid: control 'DataGridView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on."

Comment: No , the error comes at Form2 line:7 which is "Form1.ListOfNames.Add(myName)". ListOfNames is the DataSource for DataGridView1

Comment: Thank you so much for the swift updates by the way !, seems like its progressing , i have changed as you suggested and now the error message is different but at the same line 7 on Form 2, the error message is : System.InvalidOperationException: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created"

Comment: sorry, this was removed already when we created a method to do the invoke, above said error was throwing when that BeginInvoke was there on FormLoad as well as when was not there

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/808867/invoke-or-begininvoke-cannot-be-called-on-a-control-until-the-window-handle-has

Comment: Thanks Matt Wilko your suggestions and that link helped me to sort it out, i am posting final codes here is it helps anyone,

Answer (score 0):

Finally after every one's suggestion and testing below changes on Form2 button click as well as adding few methods on the Form1 solved the issue:

Added there methods on Form1

```
Private Shared ListOfNames As BindingList(Of Names) = New BindingList(Of Names)
Private Delegate Sub AddNameToListDelegate(newName As Names)

Public Sub InvokeANDCreateHandle(ByVal newNames As Names)
    Try
        If Me.IsHandleCreated = False Then
            Me.CreateHandle()
        End If
        DataGridView1.Invoke(New AddNameToListDelegate(AddressOf AddNameToList), newNames)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub AddNameToList(name As Names)
    ListOfNames.Add(name)
End Sub
```

And Changed Button Click on From2 to :

```
 Private Sub btnTestFromDiffTread_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTestFromDiffTread.Click
    Try
        Dim myName As Names = New Names
        myName.FullName = "John Peter"
        Form1.InvokeANDCreateHandle(myName)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
 End Sub
```