# Locking does not prevent InvalidOperationException: Object is currently in use elsewhere

Tags: c#, bitmap, locking, invalidoperationexception

I was under the impression that `lock()` would prevent multiple threads from accessing an object simultaneously.

But, an InvalidOperationException (Object is currently in use elsewhere) is still frequently thrown by the following code:

```
lock (this)
{
    localCopy = (Bitmap)this.bm.Clone();
    int x, y;
    float pX = this.p.x;
    int width = localCopy.Width;
    x = (int)Math.Round((double)(pX * (float)width));
    if (x >= localCopy.Width) x = localCopy.Width - 1;
    y = (int)Math.Round((double)(this.p.y * (float)localCopy.Height));
    if (y >= localCopy.Height) y = localCopy.Height - 1;
    colourPixel = localCopy.GetPixel(x, y);
}
```

Some things to note:

- I split up the calculation of `x` to isolate the cause of the exception. It appears to come from accessing the bitmap.
- I tried creating a local copy of the bitmap, but this just causes the same exception. I've tried `Clone()`ing and creating a new Bitmap. Neither works.
- I've tried locking on `this` (as seen) and on the bitmap object. Neither works.

Am I trying to use `lock()` in a way I'm not supposed to? Have I misunderstood it's purpose? How can I prevent `InvalidOperationException`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually got to the bottom of this. I moved the locks into the getter / setter methods of the bitmap property and implemented a "deep copy" method to free up the property as soon as possible.

```
private static object syncRoot = new Object();
private Bitmap _bm;
private Bitmap bm
{
    get
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
            return this._bm.DeepClone();
    }
    set
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            this._bm = value.DeepClone();
        }
    }
}
```

The DeepClone() extension method was cribbed from [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1213649/50151):

```
public static T DeepClone<T>(this T a)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, a);
        stream.Position = 0;
        return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: glad to see that part of my answer worked. That deep clone is very useful, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Probably try using an object for locking purpose rather than locking "this".

A class level variable

```
private static object syncRoot = new Object();
```

and when you are using

```
lock (syncRoot)
{
....
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but accessing `this.bm` still results in an InvalidOperationException.

Comment: Tom, is it possible that issue is other than lock ? I ask because the description of InvalidOperationException says "InvalidOperationException is used in cases when the failure to invoke a method is caused by reasons other than invalid arguments."
And BitMap.Clone really takes couple of different input parameters !

Comment: You may have misread that. Since it says "reasons OTHER than invalid arguments", the parameters of `Bitmap.Clone()` seem irrelevant. Besides, the issue occurs even when I use new `Bitmap(Bitmap)`.

Comment: Yup. Misread that..probably http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851292/invalidoperationexception-object-is-currently-in-use-elsewhere may throw some light.

Comment: @TomWright: As stated in the link above, the thread which creates the bitmap locks it. Some locking in the GDI.