# Object is currently in use somewhere else error when using Paraller.For

Tags: c#, parallel.for

I am trying to parallelize an operation on an image using the code below , but I get an `One or more errors occurred` error.

Looking into the inner exception I can see the error `{"Object is currently in use elsewhere."}` has occurred.

Note: `CoverImage` and `SecretImage` are `Bitmap`s

```
 Parallel.For(0, CoverImage.Width, x =>
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < CoverImage.Height; y++, SecretImageHeight++)
                {
                    Color coverImagesPixel = CoverImage.GetPixel(x, y);
                    Color secretImagesPixel = SecretImage.GetPixel(SecretImageWidth, SecretImageHeight);

                    int r = (coverImagesPixel.R & coverImageMask) + ((secretImagesPixel.R >> shift) & secretImageMask);
                    int g = (coverImagesPixel.G & coverImageMask) + ((secretImagesPixel.G >> shift) & secretImageMask);
                    int b = (coverImagesPixel.B & coverImageMask) + ((secretImagesPixel.B >> shift) & secretImageMask);

                    StegoImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b));
                }
                SecretImageHeight = 0;
                SecretImageWidth++;
            }
            );
```

I tried using a mutex like this :

```
mutex.WaitOne();
StegoImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(255, r, g, b));
mutex.ReleaseMutex();
```

But still to no avail (I get the same error).

Comment: What types are CoverImage and SecretImage?  Are they in use in the application elsewhere?  What happens when you wrap access to them in the mutex - they might be causing the problem as well.

Comment: If you follow the exception, which line causes it? I'm guessing either `SecretImage` or `CoverImage` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @thorkia:They are of type Bitmap.
@ Flindeberg: It just highlights the Parallel.For block altogether

Comment: @Hossein Have you tried changing to a non-parallel loop then adding a break point inside the loop and walking through it to see where the exception is being thrown?  I suspect Jon Skeet is right and you either have to copy the images to a bytearray or dispatch the access to them on the UI thread

Comment: possible duplicate of [InvalidOperationException - object is currently in use elsewhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1851292/invalidoperationexception-object-is-currently-in-use-elsewhere)

Comment: @thorkia:Working on that at the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use image APIs from non-UI threads. That's a bad idea.

I suggest you copy the image to a byte array on the UI thread, then run your parallel for loop which would mutate the array, then recreate the image afterwards from the byte array.

Comment: If this is WPF, the other option is the use the dispatcher and invoke the calls on the UI thread

Comment: @thorkia: But the OP is deliberately using `Parallel.For` to parallelize the work - putting each image through a UI-thread bottleneck would defeat the point.