VB.Net error in my Background Worker code - Only one Background Worker present
Source and Destination are both bitmaps that are the same size.
hgt and wid are the height and width of the images minus 1.
Here's the background worker code:
Private Sub BGWProcess_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BGWProcess.DoWork
    For Y = 0 To hgt
        For X = 0 To wid
            If BGWProcess.CancellationPending Then Exit Sub
            Destination.SetPixel(X, Y, Source.GetPixel(X, Y)) '**Here is where it fails**
        Next
        BGWProcess.ReportProgress(Y)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub BGWProcess_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BGWProcess.ProgressChanged
    TxtProgress.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString
    PictureBox1.Image = Destination
End Sub

The exception is

System.InvalidOperationException: Object is currently in use elsewhere.

at the line Destination.SetPixel(X, Y, Source.GetPixel(X, Y)).
There is nothing else going on that might be accessing any of the bitmaps or the PictureBox. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
What I tried is the code I posted and I expected it to work, it didn't and I don't know why it fails.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1852451/284240

Can you explain what you're trying to do here? Are you actually tying to copy pixels from one image to another? Why? Why not just duplicate the image? If that's the case, that's not the way to copy pixels. Otherwise, explain what's the real purpose

Why not just PictureBox1.Image = Source.Clone(New Rectangle(0, 0, Source.Width - 1, Source.Height - 1), Source.PixelFormat) ?

I want to replace one Image with another ONE ROW at a time from top to bottom.

Use a Timer to time the rendering (System.Windows.Forms.Timer). When it ticks, stop the Timer, replace one scan line, invalidate the Control used to show the Image, restart the Timer. Don't set the Timer's Interval below 35ms -- You can use SetPixel() for this. It's very slow (but good enough if you need to change 1 pixel once in a while. Or get the color of one with the GetPixel() counterpart). You should use Bitmap.LockBits()  instead (remembering that a Scan Line is always 4-bytes aligned)
