# Is calling an extension method on a "null" reference (i.e. event with no subscribers) evil?

Tags: c#, events, extension-methods

Evil or not evil?

```
public static void Raise(this EventHandler handler, object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   if (handler != null)
   {
      handler(sender, args);
   }
}

// Usage:
MyButtonClicked.Raise(this, EventArgs.Empty);

// This works too! Evil?
EventHandler handler = null;
handler.Raise(this, EVentArgs.Empty);
```

Note that due to the nature of extension methods, MyButtonClicked.Raise will not throw a NullReferenceException if MyButtonClicked is null. (E.g. there are no listeners to MyButtonClicked event).

Evil or not?

Comment: Better question: useful or not?

Comment: It's useful. Instead of littering hundreds of "if (SomeEvent != null) SomeEvent(this, args)" around our codebase, we can replace it with a single line.

Comment: Or, you could just create a 'dummy handler' for your event, to ensure it's never null.

Comment: Joel - what are the performance implications of dummy handlers? I haven't done the proofing on it but I'm willing to bet that a conditional check is less expensive than a delegate invocation.

Comment: Interesting suggestion about initializing them to an empty delegate. Seems like that would create some overhead in terms of both generated code and runtime memory.

Comment: Personally I like the idea of adding an empty delegate better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170907/is-there-a-downside-to-adding-an-anonymous-empty-delegate-on-event-declaration

Still a neat idea though :) +1

Comment: I think the code is fine, although I should point out that the code in its current form isn't thread safe.

Comment: If it's inlined it solves the thread-safety issue which requires yet another line of boilerplate if you don't use something like this

Comment: Old question, but under current "rules" it should really be closed. Still interesting to read though.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Not evil. I wish events worked this way by default. Can someone explain why an event with no subscribers is null?

Comment: I agree events without subscribers shouldn't be null. It seems rather foolish that an event with no subscribers is null - surely they could have initialized it with some reusable class with an empty subscription list. Alas, it's too late to change now.

Comment: I entirely agree, and have an overload that defaults the args argument to EventArgs.Empty.

Comment: Having events without subscribers be null is just fine.  What's broken is that trying to invoke a null event which has a void return type throws an exception.  Invoking a null delegate should throw an exception, but a field declared *as an event* should not be regarded as a delegate in such case.

Answer (score 14):

You can always declare your events like this (not that i recommend it):

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnClicked = delegate { };
```

That way they have something assigned to them when you call them, so they don't throw a null pointer exception.

You can probably get rid of the delegate keyword in C# 3.0...

Comment: I recommend it. It sticks to the good citizenship principles.

Answer (score 9):

Don't forget to use `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]`, else its possible that it isn't thread safe.

(Read that somewhere long ago, remembered it, googled and found http://blog.quantumbitdesigns.com/tag/events/ )

Answer (score 6):

Coming from a java background this has always seemed odd to me. I think that no one listening to an event is perfectly valid. Especially when listeners are added and removed dynamically.

To me this seems one of C#'s gottchas that causes bugs when people don't know / forget to check for null every time.

Hiding this implementation detail seems a good plan as it's not helping readability to check for nulls every single time. I'm sure the MSFTs will say there's a performance gain in not constucting the event if no one is listening, but imho it is vastly outweighed by the pointless null pointer exceptions / reduction in readability in most business code.

I'd also add these two methods to the class:

```
    public static void Raise(this EventHandler handler, object sender)
    {
        Raise(handler, sender, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public static void Raise<TA>(this EventHandler<TA> handler, object sender, TA args)
        where TA : EventArgs
    {
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(sender, args);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Why would it be evil?

Its purpose is clear: It raises the MyButtonClicked event.

It does add a function call overhead, but in .NET it will either be optimized away or pretty fast anyway.

It is slightly trivial, but it fixes my biggest complaint with C#.

On the whole, I think it's a fantastic idea, and will probably steal it.

Comment: It would be evil only because it won't throw an exception if MyButtonClick is null. E.g. this is valid: EventHandler click = null; click.Raise(...);

Comment: Well you can't set the EventHandler null. The only way it can be null is if no one is listening to the event, and I don't think raising an event that no one is listening to is an exception-worthy event.

Comment: Right, I just mean, if there are no subscribers to the event, it would be null. Then, calling what looks like a instance method on a potentially null object might appear to be an evil use of extension methods.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's evil, but I'm interested in how your extension method fits in with the

```
protected virtual OnSomeEvent(EventArgs e){ }
```

pattern and how it handles extensibility via inheritance.  Does it presume all subclasses will handle the event instead of override a method?

Comment: Shouldn't affect this. Inside the OnSomeEvent, you'd use the extension method instead of the normal "check for null, raise if not null" limbo dance.

Answer (score 0):

Although I wouldn't describ it as *evil*, it still has a negative implication, as it adds unnecessary overhead:

When calling

`myEvent.Raise(this, new EventArgs());`

the object EventArgs is initialized in all situations, even if no-one subscribed to myEvent.

When using

```
if (myEvent!= null) {
   myEvent(this, new EventArgs());
}
```

EventArgs is only initialized if someone subscribed to myEvent.

Comment: Yep, true. I'm willing to trade a little memory allocation for more readable, robust code.

Comment: The overhead is minimal and if you look at how all the core lbraries are done they implement the following pattern:
public void SomeMethod()
{
    OnSomeEvent(new SomeEventArgs());
}

protected virtual void OnSomeEvent(SomeEventArgs e)
{
    if (SomeEvent != null)
    {
        SomeEvent(this, e);
    }
}

Answer (score -2):

Throwing an exception when there are no handlers is not really preferable by the most. If it does not have an handlers it is better to be empty rather than null.

Comment: @MattEllen Oops, I thought it will help in knowing the general practice. Considering the programmer comfort. Thanks anyway