# Raising an event thread safely

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, events

I'm sure I've seen this around before but I'm wondering how I should raise an event thread-safely.

I have a message despatch thread which looks somthing like.

```
while(_messages > 0){

    Message msg;
    // get next message

    if (MessageDispatched != null)
        MessageDispatched(this, new MessageDispatchedEventArgs(msg.Msg, msg.Params));
}
```

I can see that it may be posible for `MessageDispatched` to be come null after the check. from a MS blog I've seen:

```
var handler = MessageDispatched;

if (handler != null)
    handler(this, new MessageDispatchedEventArgs(msg.Msg, msg.Params));
```

Which does stop the possibility of the reference becoming null after the check occurring. I'm wondering how to handle the case where the delegate is disposed (or even if it can?)

Should I just need to stick a try / catch around it, as its probably very rarely going to occur?

*Edit*

After reading answers I've considered making my class to handle this - quickly it looks something whats below, but I'm running into a few issues which make it not as clean as I want - maybe someone has an idea how to do that?

```
public class ThreadSafeEvent<TDelegate> 
// where TDelegate : Delegate        why is this a non allowed special case??? 
{
    List<TDelegate> _delegates = new List<TDelegate>();

    public void Subscribe(TDelegate @delegate)
    {

        lock (_delegates)
        {
            if (!_delegates.Contains(@delegate))
                _delegates.Add(@delegate);
        }
    }

    public void Unsubscibe(TDelegate @delegate)
    {
        lock (_delegates)
        {
            _delegates.Remove(@delegate);
        }
    }


    // How to get signature from delegate?
    public void Raise(params object[] _params)
    {
        lock (_delegates)
        {
            foreach (TDelegate wrappedDel in _delegates)
            {
                var del = wrappedDel as Delegate;
                del.Method.Invoke (del.Target,  _params);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue with the code you added via edit is a possible deadlock.  Consider this: an object subscribes to your handler.  On thread A, a lock is acquired.  On thread B, something happens that requires the event to be raised.  In the handler for that, it tries to acquire the lock held by thread A, blocking.  Thread A then tries to register a handler on the event, leading to a deadlock (each thread holds a lock the other is waiting on).  IMHO, this is worse than either of the other issues (the NullRef from doing nothing, or the phantom event from the MS-recommended way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter structure will make sure you won't get a null reference exception calling the handler on non-Itanium architectures.

However, it leads to another possible issue -- it's possible for a client that registered an event handler to have the handler called *after* it's been removed.  The only way to prevent that is to serialize raising the event and registering the handler.  However, if you do that, you have a potential deadlock situation.

In short, there are three potential classes of ways this can break -- I go with the way you've done it here (and MS recommends) and accept that it is possible for an event handler to get called after it is unregistered.

Answer (score 0):

Please, check this out: [Checking for null before event dispatching… thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282653/checking-for-null-before-event-dispatching-thread-safe/282741#282741)

Answer (score 0):

Read this post from Eric Lippert : [Events and Races](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx)