# Why is an additional if statement to check if an event is null before invoking it?

Tags: c#, .net, events, visual-studio-2012, delegates

I am going through this code below:

```
public delegate void PersonArrivedEventHandler(string personName, byte[] personId);

    public class SCLib
    {
        public event personArrivedEventHandler personrrived;

        public SCLib()
        {
            // Simulate that the person arrived after 2000 milli-seconds.
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                OnPersonArrived("personName", new byte[] { 0x20, 0x21, 0x22 });
            });
        }

        protected virtual void OnPersonArrived(string smartCardReaderName, byte[] smartCardId)
        {
            if (this.personArrived != null)
            {
                PersonArrived(personName, personId);
            }
        }
    }
```

But, I don't know what is the significance of this line,
`if (this.personArrived != null)`.

Why is this check done here? Is there any significance of the `if statement` here? I removed this line and ran the program and everything works as before.

Thanks.

Comment: "I just removed all the smoke detectors from the house and everything in it kept working as it did before, so I guess smoke detectors are unnecessary". No: everything *except the smoke detectors* worked as before. When you remove a safety system that safety system no longer operates.

Comment: @EricLippert: Nice analogy. Made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the event is not subscribed by the consumer of the `class` then invoking the `event` would raise exception as `PersonArrived` is null if not subscribed.

Comment: thanks, and just checked without subscribing to the event and it was null as you said. But internally how does a class know somebody has or not subscribed to its event ?

Comment: It would be null if the object on which it is going to be called does not subscribe it.

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. `But internally how does a class know somebody has or not subscribed to its event ?` . Well, the answer is: through its object state.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an event which you have not assign a handler it will generate an exception because it is null, so you need to check it before launch the event.

Answer (score 1):

Because it will be null if no delegates are attached to the event. If you try to invoke such a null event you will get the standard `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 1):

'Events' are subscribe by class object using add handler.

`SCLibObject.personrrived += new personArrivedEventHandler(somemethod)`

If class object is not subscribe the event then you will get `NullReferenceException`. So before calling events check if it is null or not.

Answer (score 1):

In a multi-threading application you should store the eventhandlers in a local variable before invoking. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/282741/261050), [this blog post from Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786383/c-sharp-events-and-thread-safety) for more details.

```
void SomeEventInvoke(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    EventHandler ev = SomeEvent;
    if (ev != null) ev(sender, args);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Links seem to be really useful.