# C# - Why is VS 2017 greying out null check on event object?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When doing a null check on an event object, Visual Studio is changing the code color to light grey. If I'm not mistaken , it normally implies that this line is unnecessary. Obviously, it is not the case in my situation (or is it ?). See my example below:

```
 public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    string test; 

    protected void OnPropertyChanged (string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) {    //This line is grey
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }  //This line is grey
        if (test != null) {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Here is the screen shot:
[image]

Comment: It means that the code can be simplified. Probably something like `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...)`

Comment: When you hover that, it should be explained.

Comment: @bommelding I did, there's is no information provided

Comment: Mouseover the ... and it will offer up `?.Invoke`

Comment: Yes or click on the grey line and press `Ctrl+.` or `Alt+Enter`

Comment: As it stands, there's a race condition that disappears with the use of `?.Invoke`.

Comment: Then your hover is broken.

Comment: @bommelding that's strange, I restarted my VS and now it appears. I guess it was indeed broken. Couldn't see the glorious light bulb...

Comment: @spender - true but VS (or R#) is not clever enough to detect that. The hint is just about the simplification.

Comment: @spender So it has to do with more than just simplification ?

Comment: I don't know what the warning pertains to but there's certainly a problem with your original approach. Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/282653/checking-for-null-before-event-dispatching-thread-safe) I asked (almost in SO's pre-history) will help you understand.

Comment: @spender damn thank you for the link. Glad I asked!

Comment: @scharette And [another article](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2015/01/30/clean-event-handlers-invocation-with-c-6/) by the [Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) about why the info in that old question is now stale...

Comment: @spender Kinda sad I can't call it has PropertyChanged?(...), but oh well...

Comment: @scharette I'd second that, but at least it's a good deal less pre-requisite knowledge that was previously required when trying to make a robust event system.

Comment: @spender true... Anyway, thanks a lot for the articles really helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you right click and view ([Quick Actions and Refactorings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quick-actions)) the suggested fix you will see that the `null` reference check can be performed on the same line as the raising of the event through the use of the `?` operator (Safe Navigation Operator).

The action it will suggest is the following:

```
this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

Comment: Wow, that was simple. Thanks a lot for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a code suggestion.  If you hover your cursor over it, you will see a little "Quick Actions" icon in the margin, and if you click it you will see that it's suggesting you could improve your statement -- make it more succinct -- by using a null conditional operator:

[image]

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
```

Comment: +1 for ss. After restarting my VS that's exactly how I could see it. It even suggest potential fixes. Thanks for your insight