# How to correctly unregister an event handler

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

In a code review, I stumbled over this (simplified) code fragment to unregister an event handler:

```
 Fire -= new MyDelegate(OnFire);
```

I thought that this does not unregister the event handler because it creates a new delegate which had never been registered before. But searching MSDN I found several code samples which use this idiom.

So I started an experiment:

```
internal class Program
{
    public delegate void MyDelegate(string msg);
    public static event MyDelegate Fire;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Fire += new MyDelegate(OnFire);
        Fire += new MyDelegate(OnFire);
        Fire("Hello 1");
        Fire -= new MyDelegate(OnFire);
        Fire("Hello 2");
        Fire -= new MyDelegate(OnFire);
        Fire("Hello 3");
    }

    private static void OnFire(string msg)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnFire: {0}", msg);
    }

}
```

To my surprise, the following happened:

1. `Fire("Hello 1");` produced two messages, as expected.
2. `Fire("Hello 2");` produced one message!
   This convinced me that unregistering `new` delegates works!
3. `Fire("Hello 3");` threw a `NullReferenceException`.
    Debugging the code showed that `Fire` is `null` after unregistering the event.

I know that for event handlers and delegate, the compiler generates a lot of code behind the scene. But I still don't understand why my reasoning is wrong.

What am I missing?

Additional question: from the fact that `Fire` is `null` when there are no events registered, I conclude that everywhere an event is fired, a check against `null` is required.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

The C# compiler's default implementation of adding an event handler calls `Delegate.Combine`, while removing an event handler calls `Delegate.Remove`:

```
Fire = (MyDelegate) Delegate.Remove(Fire, new MyDelegate(Program.OnFire));
```

The Framework's implementation of `Delegate.Remove` doesn't look at the `MyDelegate` object itself, but at the method the delegate refers to (`Program.OnFire`). Thus, it's perfectly safe to create a new `MyDelegate` object when unsubscribing an existing event handler. Because of this, the C# compiler allows you to use a shorthand syntax (that generates exactly the same code behind the scenes) when adding/removing event handlers: you can omit the `new MyDelegate` part:

```
Fire += OnFire;
Fire -= OnFire;
```

When the last delegate is removed from the event handler, `Delegate.Remove` returns null. As you have found out, it's essential to check the event against null before raising it:

```
MyDelegate handler = Fire;
if (handler != null)
    handler("Hello 3");
```

It's assigned to a temporary local variable to defend against a possible race condition with unsubscribing event handlers on other threads. (See [my blog post](https://faithlife.codes/blog/2008/11/events_and_threads_part_4/) for details on the thread safety of assigning the event handler to a local variable.) Another way to defend against this problem is to create an empty delegate that is always subscribed; while this uses a little more memory, the event handler can never be null (and the code can be simpler):

```
public static event MyDelegate Fire = delegate { };
```

Comment: Yep. To supplement: this confused me for a while too, especially since in C# you can do

Fire += new MyDelegate(OnFire)

or

Fire += OnFire;

The latter appears to be simpler, but is just syntactic sugar for the former.

Comment: @Nicholas Piasecki: Thanks; I updated my answer to note that (rather useful) shorthand.

Comment: It may be worth noting that adding a multicast delegate and later unsubscribing it may yield incorrect results if any of the methods within that multicast delegate are also subscribed and unsubscribed individually.

Answer (score 15):

You should always check whether a delegate has no targets (its value is null) before firing it.
As said before, one way of doing this is to subscribe with a do-nothing anonymous method which won't be removed.

```
public event MyDelegate Fire = delegate {};
```

However, this is just a hack to avoid NullReferenceExceptions.

Just simply cheking whether a delegate is null before invoking is not threadsafe as an other thread can deregister after the null-check and making it null when invoking.
There is an other solution is to copy the delegate into a temporary variable:

```
public event MyDelegate Fire;
public void FireEvent(string msg)
{
    MyDelegate temp = Fire;
    if (temp != null)
        temp(msg);
}
```

Unfortunately, the JIT compiler may optimize the code, eliminate the temporary variable, and use the original delegate. (as per Juval Lowy - Programming .NET Components)

So to avoid this problem, you could use method which accepts a delegate as parameter:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public void FireEvent(MyDelegate fire, string msg)
{
    if (fire != null)
        fire(msg);
}
```

Note that without the MethodImpl(NoInlining) attribute the JIT compiler could inline the method making it worthless.
Since delegates are immutable this implementation is threadsafe.
You could use this method as:

```
FireEvent(Fire,"Hello 3");
```

Comment: Thanks very much for clarifying the JIT issues. Traps and pitfalls everywhere.

Comment: Actually, this is not possible with Microsoft's CLR 2.0, due to its stronger memory model: http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/11/events_and_threads_part_4.html