# How to desubscribe an event

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to correctly unregister an event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292820/how-to-correctly-unregister-an-event-handler)

If I have registered an event as following

```
List.Changed += new ChangedEventHandler(ListChanged);
```

what should be the best way of de registering it in destructor

```
List.Changed -= new ChangedEventHandler(ListChanged);
```

or

```
List.Changed -=ListChanged;
```

Answer (score 1):

the second option is just shorthand

Answer (score 0):

The second option. And you can subscribe to it the same way:

```
List.Changed += ListChanged;
```