# Stop int from increasing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My game has a score. The score is represented by gameobjects. The score increases by 10 on a collision event. These events can not be stopped. I would like for the score to stop increasing on conditional "GameOver".

I am wondering how to stop the score from increasing since the triggering event can not be stopped. Making score = 0 is not good because I want to have the player's end score displayed. I need to somehow disconnect the score from the instantiations at the time of GameOver. Or I need to make the score integer stay the same at the time of GameOver. This is really a conceptual question and I'm not sure how to tackle this problem. Any ideas?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


public class ScoreHandler : MonoBehaviour {
public int score = 0;
public List<GameObject> destroyList = new List<GameObject>();
public static GameObject[] Score;



// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    score -= 80;

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}



void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
    if (col.gameObject.name == "carA") {
        score += 10;


    }
    if(col.gameObject.name == "carB")
    {
        score += 10;


    }
    if(col.gameObject.name == "carC")
    {
        score += 10;

    }
    if(col.gameObject.name == "carD")
    {
        score += 10;


    }
    if(col.gameObject.name == "carE")
    {
        score += 10;


    }
    if(col.gameObject.name == "carF")
    {
        score += 10;


    }
    if(col.gameObject.name == "carG")
    {
        score += 10;


    }
    if(col.gameObject.name == "carH")
    {
        score += 10;

    }


    foreach (var go in destroyList)
    {
        Destroy(go);
    }
    destroyList.Clear();


    string scoreText = score.ToString ();


    Score = new GameObject[scoreText.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < scoreText.Length; i++) {

        Score[i] = (GameObject)Instantiate (Resources.Load (scoreText 
[i].ToString ()));

        Score[i].layer = 8;
        Score[i].transform.localScale = new Vector3 (0.02F, 0.02F, 
0.02F);
        Score[i].transform.localPosition = new Vector3 (0.013F + i * 
0.01F, 0.12F, 0.0F);
        Score[i].transform.Rotate (0, 180, 0);

        destroyList.Add (Score[i]);



    }
  }

}
```

*This code box has a scroll bar.

Comment: Did you try unregistering the event handler once the game is over? See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/292840/1977871

Comment: I read that a few times but I'm having trouble imagining it in this context. How do you think it would look in this app?

Comment: Or add a check against a `GameOver` flag.

Comment: YourObjectThatDefinesEven.YourEvent -­= OnCollisionEnter; This code should execute once the game is over.

Comment: Just do `if(score<10)` check, before increasing score.

Comment: Why so many if conditions if all are doing same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `GameOver` flag, things will get easier.

Suppose you have a flag called when game over occurs:

```
bool gameOverFlag = false;
.... //something else
void OnGameOver(){
    .... //something else
    gameOverFlag = true;
    .... //something else
}
```

And, only not to add score (while leaving everything else the same) when game over flag is `true` on collision `event` would be quite straight-forward:

```
if (col.gameObject.name == "carA") {
    score += gameOverFlag ? 0 : 10; //this is where ternary operator will come really handy
    //something else specific for carA, not for score
}
```

By implementing something like above, only your score won't be changed on collision

Comment: Thanks for the help this worked perfectly. I didn't know this technique before so I learned something new too. Thanks again Ian this helped a lot.

Comment: You are welcome. ;) You could search more about ternary operator as well as writing flag. Yes, those are not uncommon.

Comment: @learncode999 another thing you want to note if your car object all do the same thing, you may want to replace your multiple `if` with single `if` by comparing the first three letters of the `gameObject.name`. You can do it easily with `string.StartsWith`, that is `if ((col.gameObject.name.StartsWith("car"))` //do something.

Answer (score 0):

Why are objects colliding if the game is over?

One easy way to keep the game running in the background but stop the interaction is to disable the collider of the player when game is over.

```
GetComponent<Collider>().enabled = false;
```

One other solution would be to check if game is running and only add score then.

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
    if(!gameRunning)
        return;

    // score logic
}
```

However, I would recommend that you separate your code parts to be able to control the different states of your game. If you don't want to use a State Machine you could use Enum States. This will make it easier to manage as your game gets more complex.

Comment: If I disable collisions, my GameObjects fly off of the map because there is nothing to stop them. Setting thrust = 0 is not working for me either. I will think more about it and then comment what I figure out. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

Just check if score is `< 10` and also I suggest moving all your conditions in one block:

```
void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col)
{
    if ((col.gameObject.name == "carA" || col.gameObject.name == "carB" || col.gameObject.name == "carC"
      || col.gameObject.name == "carD" || col.gameObject.name == "carE"
      || col.gameObject.name == "carF" || col.gameObject.name == "carG"
      || col.gameObject.name == "carH") && score < 10 ) 
    {
        score += 10;
    }

//Rest of the code
}
```