# Proper way of raising events from C++/CLI?

Tags: events, c++-cli, raise

I was wondering what's the proper way of raising events from C++/CLI. In C# one s[hould first make a copy of the handler, check if it's not null, and then call it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340610/create-empty-c-event-handlers-automatically#340638). Is there a similar practice for C++/CLI?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

C++/CLI allows you to override `raise` in [**custom event**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f3csfsa.aspx) handlers so you don't have to test for `null` or copy when raising the event. Of course, inside your custom `raise` you still have to do this.

Example, adapted from the MSDN for correctness:

```
public delegate void f(int);

public ref struct E {
   f ^ _E;
public:
   void handler(int i) {
      System::Console::WriteLine(i);
   }

   E() {
      _E = nullptr;
   }

   event f^ Event {
      void add(f ^ d) {
         _E += d;
      }
      void remove(f ^ d) {
        _E -= d;
      }
      void raise(int i) {
         f^ tmp = _E;
         if (tmp) {
            tmp->Invoke(i);
         }
      }
   }

   static void Go() {
      E^ pE = gcnew E;
      pE->Event += gcnew f(pE, &E::handler);
      pE->Event(17);
   }
};

int main() {
   E::Go();
}
```

Answer (score 32):

This isn't the whole story!  You don't usually have to worry about null event handlers in C++/CLI.  The code for these checks is generated for you.  Consider the following trivial C++/CLI class.

```
public ref class MyClass
{
public:
    event System::EventHandler ^ MyEvent;
};
```

If you compile this class, and disassemble it using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), you get the following c# code.

```
public class MyClass
{
    // Fields
    private EventHandler <backing_store>MyEvent;

    // Events
    public event EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] add
        {
            this.<backing_store>MyEvent = (EventHandler) Delegate.Combine(this.<backing_store>MyEvent, value);
        }
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)] remove
        {
            this.<backing_store>MyEvent = (EventHandler) Delegate.Remove(this.<backing_store>MyEvent, value);
        }
        raise
        {
            EventHandler <tmp> = null;
            <tmp> = this.<backing_store>MyEvent;
            if (<tmp> != null)
            {
                <tmp>(value0, value1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The usual checks are being done in the raise method.  Unless you really want custom behavior, you should feel comfortable declaring your event as in the above class, and raising it without fear of a null handler.

Comment: My problem with this approach is that the "raise" method is not private (like in C#) and shows in the intellisense.

Comment: @Filip: So go with a custom event and put `private:` in front.

Answer (score 7):

If your issue is that ***raise*** isn't private, then explicitly implement it like the docs say:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5f3csfsa.aspx

In summary:

If you just use the ***event*** keyword, you create a "trivial" event.  The compiler generates ***add***/***remove***/***raise*** and the delegate member for you.  The generated ***raise*** function (as the docs say) checks for ***nullptr***.  Trivial events are documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b612y2s.aspx

If you want "more control", for example to make ***raise*** private, then you have to explicitly implement the members as shown in the link.  You must explicitly declare a data member for the delegate type.  Then you use the ***event*** keyword to declare the event-related members, as in the Microsoft example:

```
// event keyword introduces the scope wherein I'm defining the required methods
// "f" is my delegate type
// "Event" is the unrealistic name of the event itself
event f^ Event
{
      // add is public (because the event block is public)
      // "_E" is the private delegate data member of type "f"
      void add(f ^ d) { _E += d; }

   // making remove private
   private:
      void remove(f ^ d) { _E -= d; }

   // making raise protected
   protected:
      void raise(int i)
      { 
         // check for nullptr
         if (_E)
         {
            _E->Invoke(i);
         }
      }
}// end event block
```

Wordy, but there it is.

-reilly.