# How can I provide a delegate in a managed interface class

Tags: .net, delegates, c++-cli

I am working on a project containing parts of C#, managed C++ as well as unmanaged C++ code. I am working with .NET 3.5.

My programming experience lies more on the unmanaged C++ side an I am not that familiar with the concepts of .NET.

My question is: How can I hide / provide a delegate behind a managed interface class.

Suppose my interface looks sth. like this...

```
// I guess this is a type definition so it has to be placed outside of the interface
delegate void SignalStrengthDelegate(short input);

public interface class Test
{
    event SignalStrengthDelegate^ signalStrengthChanged;

    void doSomething();
};
```

... then I get an compiler-error in the ref class implementing this interface. The error suggests that i should implement methods for adding an removing the delegates. After trying to do this the compiler asks me to switch to /clr:oldSyntax... so that's also not what I am looking for.

I googled around a lot but can't find any suggestions for my problem... at some point I have the feeling that delegates and interfaces are some kind of contrary concepts and should not be mixed.

Any suggestions?

TIA!

Answer (score 3):

The documentation provides some examples:

- [event keyword (C++/CLI)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b612y2s.aspx)
- [How to: Access Events in Interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58cwt3zh.aspx)
- [How to: Define Event Accessor Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw1dtw0d.aspx)
- [How to: Implement Abstract Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d78b9ay6.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're declaring an event - and an event is basically an add/remove pair. That's why you're getting the compiler error. I suspect that you *can* do this, just not with the syntax you've been using. It would be very odd if you couldn't implement events in C++/CLI.

You may want to read my article on [events, delegates and the differences between them](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter2/Events.aspx).

What are you *really* trying to do? Do you want a property of the delegate type? Or a method which has the delegate type as a parameter? You say you want to "hide / provide a delegate" - what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Jon, C#4 seems to handle an event in an interface fine. It just forces you to repeat it in the implementing classes.

Comment: @Henk: Yes, C# has always allowed you to specify an event in an interface. It's the implementation in C++ which is causing the OP grief, I believe.

Comment: Thank you! What I am trying to do is to provide an c++/cli-interface which hides the implementation from the C#-caller (the interface will be part of an API used by some other guys and I want to hide some methods from them that are used in the c++/cli-parts); in reference to the snipped above and assuming there is a class TestImpl that implements the interface Test, the C#-code should look sth. like this...

Test test = new TestImpl();
test.signalStrengthChanged +=new Test.SignalStrengthDelegate(signalStrengthChanged);

Comment: ... so Jon, you are right... the implementation of the interface causes my problem; I just don't know how to satisfy the compiler. :)

Comment: @Superfisi: Unfortunately I don't know the C++/CLI syntax for it - but it looks like Ben's links will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I dug up an article that seems to show the proper syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163659.aspx

Comment: That's not C++/CLI.  Please let Managed Extensions for C++ die the horrible death it deserves.

Comment: @Ben: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462805/proper-way-of-raising-events-from-c-cli closer to the mark?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't cover this question which is about abstract events.

Comment: @Ben: And it looks like you already posted a link to a good example of abstract events.  At this point, I think it's probably best to upvote you and delete this answer, as it's redundant at best.