# Wiring up events from dll loaded at runtime?

Tags: c#

Basically I want to be able to write a dll for my application  that I will be able to put in a specific folder using a specific name and at runtime have that dll loaded and subscribe to a specific event.
As an example I have a simple Windows Form App with a single button on it. I want to be able to have a MessageBox displayed when the button click event takes place but I want the displayed message to be controlled by an external dll that is loaded at runtime.
What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an interface that includes at least one method to handle the event (your application will have to reference the assembly in which this is defined):

```
public interface IEventHandler {
    void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e);
}
```

Add a class to the dll you want to load at runtime that implements the interface:

```
public class ConcreteEventHandler: IEventHandler {
    public void HandleEvent(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

In your application, use reflection to load the dll and create an instance of your concrete handler (error checking omitted):

```
// The assembly name/location could be configurable
Assembly      assembly = Assembly.Load("MyAssembly.dll");
// The type name could be configurable
Type          type     = assembly.GetType("ConcreteEventHandler");
IEventHandler handler  = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IEventHandler;
```

You can hook this handler up to whatever you want, e.g.:

```
MyButton.OnClick += handler.HandleEvent;
```

Comment: Thanks. When I get to the last line of you sample code which I change from MyButton.OnClick += handler.HandleEvent to MyButton.Click += HandleEvent I am getting "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" error on this line. What am I missing?

Comment: You can ignore the above comment regarding the null reference error. I copied the dll to a sep dir to import at runtime and then continued to work in Visual Studio so the dll I was working on was not the dll that was working on. Duh. Thanks. You example was very helpful.

Comment: That's one of the eternal pitfalls of loading 'pluggable' assemblies via reflection - if you think of a good way around it, let us know! :) The best I can recommend is to add code to check for everything and throw very specific exceptions, like: `if (! File.Exists(assemblyPath)) { throw new FileNoteFoundException(string.Format("Cannot locate assembly at {0}.", assemblyPath)); }`. (And add something similar for type, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Is the DLL a single well-known one or will you be loading different or multiple ones?  If the latter, I suggest looking into the `AddIn` framework in .NET 3.5.

Given either of those choices, a very good design pattern to employ in this case is the [Observer pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249517/super-simple-example-of-c-observer-observable-with-delegates/1249790#1249790).  Your "observers" are watching the button click event (the observed) and execute their `MessageBox`(es) appropriately.