# How to share one value among multiple objects? C#

Tags: c#

Is it possible to have some variable shared between some objects of the same class such that, when the value is changed in one object, it will also change in the other object? Static variables would not work in this case, because there could be 2 objects that all have some related variable and another 2 objects that have a different related variable.

For example, say I have 4 squares that are arranged to make one large square, and the squares coordinates lie in an x,y,z plane. When the 4 squares are together, they would all have a point that lies in the center of the biggest square.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ronmiech at www.math.ucla.edu](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eronmiech/Calculus_Problems/32B/chap13/section6/865d11/IMG00002.GIF))</sub>

Pretend this square also has a z coordinate. Now, the squares will all share the point that lies in the center. The top left square's bottom right corner, the top right square's bottom left corner, etc., will all have the same (x, y, z) value.

Now what I want, is such that if the z value of one square changes, they will all change without any extra code, like they all point to the same memory location, so they "automatically" update in a sense.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: If the variable is a reference type and each instance of the variable points to the same reference? [MSDN Passing Reference-Type Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z(v=vs.71).aspx#vclrfpassingmethodparameters_referencetypes)

Comment: It doesn't look like that is quite what I am after, because the values must remain pointing to the same memory location throughout the whole program, not just when a method is called. Also, the memory location must be pointed to by each object BEFORE the change is made anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way you could do this. Each square's data property is pointing to the same reference.

```
class Square 
{
     private SharedData Data;

     public Square(SharedData data)
     {
        this.Data = data;
     }
}

class SharedData
{
     public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

---

```
SharedData data = new SharedData() { Z = 100.0 }

Square topLeft = new Square(data);
Square topRight = new Square(data);
Square bottomLeft = new Square(data);
Square bottomRight = new Square(data);
```

---

You can put `SharedData` behind an interface that provides read-only access to the squares if you wish. If the squares are not supposed to modify the value of Z this would be a safer approach.

```
interface IReadOnlyData
{
    double GetZ();
}

class SharedData : IReadOnlyData
{
     public double Z { get; set; }
     IReadOnlyData.GetZ() { return Z; }
}

class Square
{
    private IReadOnlyData Data;

    public Square(IReadOnlyData data)
    {
        this.Data = data;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay... so lets say I have this implemented. Then, if I changed the value of Z of any square that held the same shared data, would the other objects SharedData object also change automatically?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. C# passes all classes by reference which means each square is receiving the memory address of the exact same object (even though the actual memory address is encapsulated by the reference). If one changes the data held in that memory block, all the other squares pointing to the same memory would see the updated value. It's worth noting that if the squares operate on separate threads you would have to use locks or another synchronization technique to avoid data corruption.

Comment: Okay great, that answers my question! Now I need to try it out and see if it will end up helping as much as I'm hoping :p. It should save a bit on memory and speed if all goes well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are thinking about this the wrong way. If all of the squares are to be treated as logically one object, make one object that encapsulates all of them and provides the logic you want. You shouldn't have objects sneakily mutating other objects' values behind their backs, IMO.

Comment: Yes I can see how that could work, however, the squares also each have their own properties besides their coordinates, and would become far more complicated to implement it that way. Of course I could accomplish it that way but it would be far more difficult. So the original question still stands of whether it is possible.

Comment: @Colton Your encapsulating object can have an `ArrayList<Square>` and, when you call methods on the encapsulation, it alters all of the `Square`s correctly.

Comment: The issue with that would be keeping track of which squares are tied to other squares. It could be done, but it would get messy.

Comment: @Colton Keeping track of which squares are tried to other squares? Sounds like something you could use a fancy data structure for, like some kind of dictionary or something. Honestly, I can't think of a best suggestion for you without knowing more about your use cases for these squares. Like if they're part of a level's map or part of a 3D model or just part of a fancy 3D effect or what.

Comment: Its more of an experiment.. Imagine a 3D model of a large piece of cloth lying flat, made up of a bunch of squares. Then, pinch the cloth on its center and pull up. The other points go with it, naturally. That is what I am trying to accomplish as simply as possible.

Comment: @Colton Aha! I thought so. In such a case instead of modelling it as a bunch of squares, you should model it as a grid of points, and when you need to render it, draw squares between the points The squares don't exist except as byproducts of the points, or if they need to have properties/texture/etc they can draw it from a parent `Cloth` object.

Comment: Yeah I like that idea, but then it would be tougher to keep track of the individual squares, I think. +1, I'll probably end up using that when my dumb idea hits a wall. :p

Answer (score 1):

Implement the observable pattern.

Check this post:
[Super-simple example of C# observer/observable with delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249517/super-simple-example-of-c-sharp-observer-observable-with-delegates)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: If I'm understanding it correctly, the values could be tied together with an event handler, but then each value would still need to be updated multiple times, instead of just once. +1 because it would work!

Comment: If you are not familiar with design patterns, take a quick look on it's wikipedia page. It will lead you on to a good start. 
It's generally the best bet if you happen to be in a situation where many many developers have been before.