# Where should I store mesh data; in static variable, it's own class, or all mesh types in one class?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, voxel

I'm trying to use Unity to make a voxel, and I wanted to do it without following a tutorial. With Minecraft in mind, as an easy example, where should I store the different mesh data's? For instance, a dirt block would have a cube mesh, and a stair would have a different mesh. Should it be different static variables in the non-static block class? For example:

```
public class Block
{
    static Vector3[] cubeVertices = new Vector3[]{input cube verts here}
    static Vector3[] stairsVertices = new Vector3[]{input stairs verts here}

    //Block data such as textures, type, etc...
    public string blockName;
    public BlockType blockType;
    public Texture blockTexture;
}
```

Then when I generate mesh just do blockInstance.cubeVertices or .stairsvertices.

The second way I thought to do it would be making separate classes for each mesh type. For example:

```
public class CubeMeshData
{
    //insert vert and tri data here
}
```

My dilemma here is I'm not sure how to choose which mesh data to use without iterating through if statements, or a switch, every time I generate a block. So, when I place a dirt block, iterate through if's to choose the cubeMesh. I feel as though the iterations would be expensive. My last choice has the same problem. A class that holds all mesh data's, with a switch to choose which. This was my first attempt so I actually have code for this:

```
public static class MeshTypes
{
    public static void ChooseMeshType(BlockType blockType, Mesh mesh)
    {
        mesh.Clear();
        switch(blockType)
        {
            case BlockType.Cube:
                mesh.vertices = new Vector3[]
                {
                    new Vector3(-1, 1, 1),
                    new Vector3(1, 1, 1),
                    new Vector3(1, 1, -1),
                    new Vector3(-1, 1, -1),
                    new Vector3(-1, -1, -1),
                    new Vector3(1, -1, -1),
                    new Vector3(1, -1, 1),
                    new Vector3(-1, -1, 1)
                };
                mesh.triangles = new int[] 
                {
                    0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3,
                    4, 5, 6, 4, 6, 7,
                    1, 0, 7, 1, 7, 6,
                    2, 1, 6, 2, 6, 5,
                    3, 2, 5, 3, 5, 4,
                    0, 3, 4, 0, 4, 7
                };
                mesh.RecalculateNormals();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the code that would call these so far:

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(MeshFilter))]
public class DrawMeshes : MonoBehaviour 
{
    Mesh mesh;

    Vector3[] verts;
    int[] tris;

    private void Awake()
    {
        mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    }

    void Start ()
    {
        MeshTypes.ChooseMeshType(BlockType.Cube, mesh);

        //CreateMesh();
    }

    private void CreateMesh()
    {
        mesh.Clear();
        mesh.vertices = CubeMesh.cubeVerts;
        mesh.triangles = CubeMesh.cubeTris;
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }
}
```

I was experimenting with MeshType.ChooseMesh if I used the MeshTypes class, and the CreateMesh if I used the separate class. That's why they are both there. I've never made anything that needed to be optimized, so I'm not knowledgeable on how expensive through a switch is.

Edit Update 8/15/18: So, I've been looking into Dictionaries. I'm not overly familiar with run times, but compared to a switch's linear iteration, a dictionary runs logarithmically. This has near constant run speed from what I've read. I believe this to be better, seeing as I want to add many different types in the future: cubes, stairs, slabs, fence, etc. Much like Minecraft. Now I just have to figure out the best way to implement it. I'll try to keep this post updated, so anyone that stumbles on it will have an answer.

Edit Update 8/18/18: I found this question: [How to share one value among multiple objects? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962663/how-to-share-one-value-among-multiple-objects-c-sharp)

I decided to use something like this for blocks. The shared data will be the cube mesh, and then I'll initialize different blocks that will use that data.

Comment: You might want to load the meshes from an external resource, for example a file. This way you can change it without modifying the binaries. Also you could add different meshes later on. So they probably endup in for example a `Dictionary<string, Mesh>`, so you can look them up on using a name.

Comment: Like with xml? I've never really used outside files like that, but it would probably be faster, right? The biggest think I'm hung up on is how to know which mesh data to use for a specific block, without iterating through something like a switch. Maybe I'm overthinking it? Would iterating through a switch or if's be expensive?

Comment: Never worked with unity. I should check it out, but you might take a look here: [Model file formats](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/3D-formats.html)

Comment: That link is for importing models, while I want to do procedural generation, at least I think. Are dictionary's quicker than iterating through a switch? Won't the dictionary have to iterate through data to pick the mesh as well?

Comment: Comparing a switch and a dictionary is a little strang. You should use a dictionary to lookup in dynamically added data. a switch is used for decision within code paths. In the end, it depends on the number of items. With less items a switch will win. With many items, you shouldn't use a switch because of bad code practice. You are talking about different meshes, cubes/stairs/etc, this should not be related to different paths within code, I would not use a switch for that. I don't want to add new code to add extra meshes.So the discussion is about  what is data and what is code structure,

Comment: So, switches are only for paths, I see. I don't want to use additional code to add separate meshes, only to store specific mesh data I can call upon. For instance, the CubeMeshData class would hold the vertices data so I can use that data whenever I generate a block that is cube shaped. I thought it would be  redundant to repeat the code for every block that shares that shape but uses a different texture.

Comment: You should reuse the mesh, because it would be stored only ones on the gpu memory. You can draw the same mesh with different textures. You could create a class Mesh which holds the vertex data and a model with refers to a Mesh and a texture.