# How do I use a void function using delegates?

Tags: c#, delegates, event-handling

I have been attempting to use event handling for a game's input. When seeing others use similar methods, they are able to add a void function to the delegate variable without an error. 
Whenever I try to add the Move() function to OnAxisChange, I receive the following error:

*Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'CharacterView.InputAction'*

```
public class CharacterView : MonoBehaviour {
    public delegate void InputAction();
    public static event InputAction OnAxisChange;

    public Vector2 InputAxis
    {
        get
        {
            float x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
            float y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
            return (new Vector2(x, y));
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {

        Vector2 input = InputAxis;
        if (input.x != 0 || input.y != 0)
        {
            if (OnAxisChange != null)
            {
                OnAxisChange();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

The following is the class that handles the event.

```
public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviour {

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        CharacterView.OnAxisChange += Move();
    }
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        CharacterView.OnAxisChange -= Move();
    }

    public void Move()
    {
        Debug.Log("Entered the move function!");
    }

}
```

Using delegates for event handling is still a bit foreign to me, so I assume I am misunderstanding something.

Comment: Instead of creating your own delegates consider using EventHandler. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @RandRandom is there some innate advantage for doing so?

Comment: The only advantage to using `EventHandler` is that it enforces the standard .NET event pattern signature of `object sender, EventArgs e`. Otherwise it is identical to using standard delegates.

Comment: @RichardMcilwain the only real reason for me is, I am a lazy bastard and prefer to use EventHandler instead of writing my own delegates. I am just trying to infect you with my laziness. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `()` after `Move`. Like that you are calling your method and try to add the return type of it which is nothing. Just change it to the following.

```
CharacterView.OnAxisChange += Move;

CharacterView.OnAxisChange -= Move;
```

Comment: Where did you get the quote `"Event declaration adds a layer of protection on the delegate instance..."` and why did you put it in the answer? What does it have to do with the question?

Comment: And why are you suggesting using a `EventHandler` rather than a delegate? It is still a delegate.

Comment: @Enigmativity I have it from another question and I put it in because he is using delegates as event handlers. EventHandlers cannot be directly reset like an delegate. Or don't you agree?

Comment: @Enigmativity but if you think it makes no difference and is even so bad that it deserves an downvote I can take it out again. I just don't uderstand why

Comment: @Enigmativity hope your happy. I still would like to know why you think it was a bad post....

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the quote. An `EventHandler` **can** be directly reset. An event declaration **cannot** be directly reset. But that doesn't relate to the use of an `EventHandler` or not.

Comment: @Enigmativity according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18170282/c-sharp-delegate-v-s-eventhandler) accepted answer it is the only reason to use events over delegates directly. Or do I misanderstand something?

Comment: Yes, you are misunderstanding. The answer you're linking to is discussing the difference between **delegates and events**, and not **delegates and `EventHandler`s**. An `EventHandler` is not an event.

Comment: @Enigmativity hm... ah now I get it. Thanks for explaining.. I feel stupi now of corese `EventHandler` is just a delegate...

Comment: So how would you go about doing the same thing, if Move required parameters?