# Avoiding null pointer exception in delegates

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, listbox, windows

I'm using [delegates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)
in my c# windows forms application project.Using that I'm trying to **remove** items in a **list box**. I'm getting this null pointer exception and can somebody suggest a way to avoid that?

**Delegate**

```
public delegate void OrderEventDelegate (Object sender, OrderEventArgs args);
```

**OrderEventArgs class**

```
public class OrderEventArgs
{
    private String message;

    public String Message
    {
        get { return message; }
        set { message = value; }
    }

    private int tableNo;

    public int TableNo
    {
        get { return tableNo; }
        set { tableNo = value; }
    }
}
```

**Class 1**

```
public partial class Class1 : Form
{
    private event OrderEventDelegate readyEvent;

    public Class1(HomeForm parent, int tableNo)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        readyEvent -= new OrderEventDelegate(parent.readyOrder);
    }

    public void button_click()
    {
        OrderEventArgs readyOrderArg = new OrderEventArgs();
        readyOrderArg.TableNo = 1;
        readyOrderArg.Message = "123";
        readyEvent(this, readyOrderArg);
    }
}
```

Here `readyEvent -= new OrderEventDelegate(parent.readyOrder);`**readyOrder()** is the method which remove items in the list, which is located in the 'Homeform'.

**Exception**
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you mean this: `readyEvent -= new OrderEventDelegate(parent.readyOrder);` and not **`+=`**

Comment: In the application there is += delegate also..but after that this -= comes :) I didnt included the += one here,but my application has it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to initialize C# events with an empty delegate. This way it can always be called safely without a null pointer check. As shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/340618/2404788.

```
public delegate void OrderEventDelegate (Object sender, OrderEventArgs args) = delegate {};
```

Answer (score 0):

If there's a possibility of something being null and you can do something about it/don't want to critically fail when it is, then check for it:

```
if (readyEvent != null) {
  readyEvent( ... );
}
```

But the point here, I suppose, is that you don't want this thing to be null; so you should subscribe a handler to the event. I'm not sure why you're trying to *remove* a `new` instance of the delegate handler, but to add one you would use `+=`.